# Slice Pandas Column containing dic value

Tags: python, json, pandas

Below is my DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['AZ', 'AF'], 'Other_Name': [np.nan, [{'name': 'ARES ZAN', 'language': 'en', 'type': 'ALTERNATIVE'}]]})


Name    Other_Name
0   AZ  NaN
1   AF  [{'name': 'ARES ZAN', 'language': 'en', 'type': 'ALTERNATIVE'}]
```

The aim is to replace 'Other_Name' column with 'Other_Name_name', 'Other_Name_language', 'Other_Name_type'

I followed the help from: [Slice pandas dataframe json column into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081097/slice-pandas-dataframe-json-column-into-columns)

Besides, as I have some NaN (which I don't want to remove), the solution isn't working.

Thanks to anyone helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
all_keys = ['name', 'language', 'type']
for key in all_keys:
  df.loc[df.Other_Name.notnull(), 'Other_Name_' + key] = df.loc[df.Other_Name.notnull(), 'Other_Name']\
                                                           .explode()\
                                                           .apply(lambda x: x[key])
```

Output:

```
    Other_Name_name     Other_Name_language     Other_Name_type
0   NaN                       NaN                  NaN
1   ARES ZAN                  en                  ALTERNATIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def change_key(x):
    for data_dict in x:
        for key in list(data_dict.keys()):
            data_dict[f'Other_Name_{key}'] = data_dict.pop(key)

    return x

df.loc[~df['Other_Name'].isnull(), 'Other_Name'] = df[~df['Other_Name'].isnull()]['Other_Name'].apply(change_key)
print(df)
```