# how to efficiently extract fields from a JSON column?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example

```
data1 = [{'type': 'one', 'delta': '1', 'time': '2019'}, {'type': 'two', 'delta': '1', 'time': '2018'}]
data2 = [{'type': 'one', 'delta': '1', 'time': '2013'}, {'type': 'two', 'delta': '1', 'time': '2012'}]


dftest = pd.DataFrame({'weirdjson' : [data1, data2]})
dftest['normalcol'] = 1

dftest

Out[79]: 
                                                                                        weirdjson  normalcol  time_type_one  time_type_two
0  [{'type': 'one', 'delta': '1', 'time': '2019'}, {'type': 'two', 'delta': '1', 'time': '2018'}]          1           2019           2018
1  [{'type': 'one', 'delta': '1', 'time': '2013'}, {'type': 'two', 'delta': '1', 'time': '2012'}]          1           2013           2012
```

Essentially, I would like to create two columns `time_type_one` and `time_type_two` that each contain their corresponding `time` value (for the first row: `2019` for `type one` and `2018` for `type two`).

How can I do that in Pandas? I have many rows so I am looking for something very efficient.
Thanks!

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think people downvoted since there's no attempt shown. Plus if we copy this dataframe, it will be copied as string column, instead of list of dictionary's. So it would be better to include your sample dataframe as copyable code with `pd.DataFrame(..)`

Comment: good point. let me change that

Comment: Since youre at it. It's also best to include an expected output in the form of a dataframe, this way people can visually see what you try to do.

Comment: I think you can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899005/how-to-flatten-a-pandas-dataframe-with-some-columns-as-json

Comment: question updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use explode, and construct a new dataframe and `unstack` type to columns as follows:

```
s = dftest.weirdjson.explode()
df_new = (pd.DataFrame({'type': s.str['type'], 'time': s.str['time']}) 
            .set_index('type', append=True).time.unstack().add_prefix('time_type_'))

Out[461]:
type time_type_one time_type_two
0             2019          2018
1             2013          2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = [{'normalcol':1, 'weirdjsoncol':'[{"type": "one", "delta": "1", "time": "2019"}, {"type": "two", "delta": "1", "time": "2018"}]'}, {'normalcol':2, 'weirdjsoncol':'[{"type": "two", "delta": "1", "time": "2017"}, {"type": "one", "delta": "1", "time": "2013"}]'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['time_type_one'] = df['weirdjsoncol'].apply(lambda x: next((i for i in json.loads(x) if i["type"] == "one"), None)["time"])

df['time_type_two'] = df['weirdjsoncol'].apply(lambda x: next((i for i in json.loads(x) if i["type"] == "two"), None)["time"])
```

Comment: nice, but what is the `next` for?

Comment: Its a Python built-in function to retrieve the next item from an iterator. You can read about it here at Python documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Comment: thanks. this looks good. I wonder whether iterating is fast or slow though. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame().append([x[y] for x in dftest.weirdjson for y in range(len(dftest.weirdjson))])
df_new = df_new.pivot(columns='type', values=['delta', 'time']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)) 
df_new.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df_new.columns.values] 

  delta_one delta_two time_one time_two
0         1         1     2019     2018
1         1         1     2013     2017
```

Comment: I updated the second line, so should work now with your dftest, i forgot the df_new =

Comment: I'm not sure how fast pivot is, i can do it another way without pivot, where i aggregrate the values as lists and expand them out, but it's a few more steps, but with shorter lines