# Extract JSON arrays into dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I have `project.json` file, which contains data like this :

```
{"student_id": "ST0001", "project": [{"subject_id": "S003", "date_of_submission": "2021-05-23 20:03:05"}, {"subject_id": "S004", "date_of_submission": "2021-05-24 21:03:05"}, {"subject_id": "S005", "date_of_submission": "2021-05-30 05:09:30"}], "project_year": "Second"}
{"student_id": "ST0002", "project": [{"subject_id": "S003", "date_of_submission": "2021-06-02 15:05:05"}, {"subject_id": "S007", "date_of_submission": "2021-04-28 21:03:01"}], "project_year": "Second"}
{"student_id": "ST0002", "project": [{"subject_id": "S0018", "date_of_submission": "2020-06-03 08:15:21"}], "project_year": "First"}
```

I need to extract the nested `subject_id` and `date_of_submission` into a separate column like :

| student_id | subject_id | date_of_submission | project_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ST0001 | S003 | 23/05/2021 20:03 | Second |
| ST0001 | S004 | 24/05/2021 21:03 | Second |
| ST0001 | S005 | 30/05/2021 05:09 | Second |
| ST0002 | S003 | 02/06/2021 15:05 | Second |
| ST0002 | S007 | 28/04/2021 21:03 | Second |
| ST0002 | S0018 | 03/06/2020 08:15 | First |

I think we can use `json_normalize` to extract one level up, can someone help me complete this;

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_json('project.json', lines=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(df).explode('project')
```

Comment: did u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899005/how-to-flatten-a-pandas-dataframe-with-some-columns-as-json

Comment: so did your query solved?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `record_path` and `meta` parameters in `json_normailze()` method:

```
s=pd.read_json('project.json',lines=True).melt()['value'].tolist()
df=pd.json_normalize(s,record_path=['project'],meta=['student_id','project_year'])
#here data is your json data
```

output of `df`:

```
subject_id  date_of_submission  student_id  project_year
0   S003    2021-05-23 20:03:05     ST0001  Second
1   S004    2021-05-24 21:03:05     ST0001  Second
2   S005    2021-05-30 05:09:30     ST0001  Second
3   S003    2021-06-02 15:05:05     ST0002  Second
4   S007    2021-04-28 21:03:01     ST0002  Second
5   S0018   2020-06-03 08:15:21     ST0002  First
```

Comment: I ran your answer changing `data` with `df`, it throws an error, `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. Can you please let me know where its incorrect?

Comment: @MNAf for the given sample json it is working...so sorry I can't tell without the data

Comment: @MNAf we read json file like this `pd.read_json()`......updated answer hope it gets clear **:)**

Comment: user:14289892 I have appended multiple json files, they don't have a square bracket as in your `data` variable. Is there a way to do using `df=pd.read_json('project.json', lines=True)`

Comment: I am still getting an error, I slightly tweaked your answer and it worked.```read_json_to_df = pd.read_json('project.json', lines=True)
json_struct = json.loads(read_json_to_df.to_json(orient="records")) 
df=pd.json_normalize(json_struct,record_path=['project'],meta=['student_id','project_year'])
df```

Comment: @MNAf if you read correctly I am reading it like `pd.read_json('project.json',typ = 'series').tolist()`

Comment: I get a `ValueError: Trailing data`, I believe the reason is there is more than one row.

Comment: @MNAf updated answer...kindly have a look and see if it works or not **:)**