# Parsing list stored as string in Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to parse a data frame column with values that look like the below. This was the result after I ran `json_normalize` on the original data set. The goal is to get the {'name':'Org Lvl 4'} value so I can then parse to just get the actual 'Org Lvl 4' name.

| index | org [dtype: Object] |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'name': 'Org Lvl 1'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 2'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 3'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 4'}] |

I read that Pandas stores this as a string not a list so I tried what others have suggested i.e. `split` but I'm getting the following error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Code:

```
df['org'] = df['org'].str.split(',').str[3]
```

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'org [dtype: Object]': {0: "[{'name': 'Org Lvl 1'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 2'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 3'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 4'}]"}})
```

Update:

After trying this I am able to print 'Org Lvl 4' for index 0 but now I need to apply this to the entire column.

```
import ast
print(df['org'].astype(str).map(ast.literal_eval)[0][3].get('name'))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solid answer, but to offer something...

Look at the answers at: [How to flatten a pandas dataframe with some columns as json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899005/)

For example:

```
import ast

def list_of_dicts(ld):
    '''
    Create a mapping of the tuples formed after 
    converting json strings of list to a python list   
    '''
    return dict([(list(d.values())[0], list(d.values())[0]) for d in ast.literal_eval(ld)])

df = pd.DataFrame({'org [dtype: Object]': {0: "[{'name': 'Org Lvl 1'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 2'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 3'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 4'}]"}})

B = pd.json_normalize(df['org [dtype: Object]'].apply(list_of_dicts).tolist()) #.add_prefix('dict_') 

print(df, '\n\n')

print(B)

>>                                  org [dtype: Object]
>> 0  [{'name': 'Org Lvl 1'}, {'name': 'Org Lvl 2'},... 


>>    Org Lvl 1  Org Lvl 2  Org Lvl 3  Org Lvl 4
>> 0  Org Lvl 1  Org Lvl 2  Org Lvl 3  Org Lvl 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve using `lambda`:

```
df['org'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(row.org)[-1]['name'])
```