# flatten a json using json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following nested dictionary with lists inside:

```
[{
    "id": 467,
    "status": 2,
    "leavePeriod": {
        "owner": {
            "employeeNumber": "2620",
            "firstName": "fn_467",
            "lastName": "ln_467"
        },
        "ownerId": 46,
        "leaves": [
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-06T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-06T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-07T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-07T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-11T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-11T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "id": 477,
    "status": 2,
    "leavePeriod": {
        "owner": {
            "employeeNumber": "2522",
            "firstName": "fn_477",
            "lastName": "lm_477"
        },
        "ownerId": 41,
        "leaves": [
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-13T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-13T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-14T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-14T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-15T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-15T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-16T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-16T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-17T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-17T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

How can I flatten it and convert it to a dataframe using this library?

```py
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

I'd like this to be done in one step if possible, instead of flattening to a dataframe twice and then merging them
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How "flat" are you wanting it? [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) will return a single row with columns `Index(['id', 'status', 'leavePeriod.owner.employeeNumber',
       'leavePeriod.owner.firstName', 'leavePeriod.owner.lastName',
       'leavePeriod.ownerId', 'leavePeriod.leaves'],
      dtype='object')`. Please provide us with an example of your desired output.

Comment: I'd like it as flat as it can be. when I use json_normalize(data), I get a nested dictionary in the leavePeriod.leaves column. I'de like to flatten it as well

Comment: @nimi1234 Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39906235/5721636) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

> Note: `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize` results in the same output on my machine but raises a `FutureWarning`.

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1


data = [{
    "id": 467,
    "status": 2,
    "leavePeriod": {
        "owner": {
            "employeeNumber": "2620",
            "firstName": "fn_467",
            "lastName": "ln_467"
        },
        "ownerId": 46,
        "leaves": [
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-06T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-06T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-07T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-07T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-11T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-04-11T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "id": 477,
    "status": 2,
    "leavePeriod": {
        "owner": {
            "employeeNumber": "2522",
            "firstName": "fn_477",
            "lastName": "lm_477"
        },
        "ownerId": 41,
        "leaves": [
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-13T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1121,
                    "name": "Vacation days 2021/2022",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1121"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-13T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-14T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-14T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-15T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-15T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-16T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-16T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-17T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "leaveAccount": {
                    "id": 1323,
                    "name": "RTT 2023",
                    "url": "https://some_link/1323"
                },
                "date": "2023-03-17T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

## Option 1

```py
# write out your meta data columns and record path
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    meta=[
        "id",
        "status",
        ["leavePeriod", "owner", "employeeNumber"],
        ["leavePeriod", "owner", "firstName"],
        ["leavePeriod", "owner", "lastName"],
        ["leavePeriod", "ownerId"]
    ],
    record_path=["leavePeriod", "leaves"]
)
```

Or if you're lazy and don't wanna split all the meta columns up by hand...

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    meta=[
        "id",
        "status",
        "leavePeriod.owner.employeeNumber".split("."),
        "leavePeriod.owner.firstName".split("."),
        "leavePeriod.owner.lastName".split("."),
        "leavePeriod.ownerId".split("."),
    ],
    record_path="leavePeriod.leaves".split(".")
)

df.sample(5)
```

[image: json_normalize out 1]
[image: json_normalize out 2]

#### Parameter Descriptions + Explanations

- `record_path`: ***str or list of str, default None***

  Path in each object to list of records. If not passed, data will be assumed to be an array of records.

> I set `record_path` to `"leavePeriod.leaves".split(".")` because that was the (nested) key(s) in the dictionary that held another layer of records, i.e. array/list of dictionaries. Leaving it blank leads `pandas` to assume that `data` is an array of records and has no further nesting.

- `meta`: ***list of paths (str or list of str), default None***

  Fields to use as metadata for each record in resulting table.

> If you set `record_path` without setting `meta` `pandas` will only normalize and extract the `record_path`. To keep the upper-level (i.e. not-so-nested) keys, we need to specify them as `meta` data.

## Option 2

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

df
```

[image: output1]

To "flatten" the `leavePeriod.leaves` even further...

```py
# explode the column and ignore index
df = df.explode(column="leavePeriod.leaves", ignore_index=True)

df.sample(5)  # taking a sample to highlight what happened
```

[image: exploded output]

```py
# convert df["leavePeriod.leaves"] to a list and use `pd.json_normalize` again
leavePeriod = pd.json_normalize(df["leavePeriod.leaves"].to_list())

leavePeriod.sample(5)
```

[image: leavePeriod output]

```py
# join `leavePeriod` with `df` 
# and drop old "leavePeriod.leaves" columns
df = (
    df.join(leavePeriod)
      .drop(columns="leavePeriod.leaves")
)

df.sample(5)
```

Note: you can't see all the columns in the image because it's too wide so I have two images

[image: joined output 1]
[image: joined output 2]

Comment: Works like a charm! thanks Ian!
Would you mind explaining the what goes into the meta and what goes into the record_path?

Comment: @nimi1234 please see my edits under ### Parameter Descriptions + Explanations

Answer (score 0):

Just use `pd.json_normalize(<put_json_here>)`.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but due to limitations I have the on the pandas version, the version that I use do not support it...

Comment: @nimi1234 what is your pandas version?