# Is there a way to flatten a pandas column of nested json strings with a varying number of objects?

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested-json

I have a pandas dataframe that is formatted similarly to this:

| order_guid | selections |
| --- | --- |
| ef23a23d-5e2c-42a0-952b-cf43732c55b8 | [{"id":"7233","item":"Smoothie"},{"guid":"6317","item":"Juice"},{"guid":"6941","item":"Chips"}] |
| 0fb69525-7b71-4dec-ab77-36a698d519f6 | [{"id":"5425","item":"Wrap"}] |
| 59b5f8e9-96f1-483b-a31d-659492765e06 | [{"id":"7233","item":"Smoothie"},{"guid":"3803","item":"Water"},{"guid":"7961","item":"Salad"}] |
| d8656ba2-4076-4036-9515-6fea1f9e58d4 | [{"id":"7961","item":"Salad"},{"guid":"5425","item":"Wrap"}] |

What I've been trying to do is unnest the `selections` field such that each selection occupies its own row with the `order_guid` as a foreign key to a separate `orders` table, similar to this:

| order_guid | selection_id | selection_item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ef23a23d-5e2c-42a0-952b-cf43732c55b8 | 7233 | Smoothie |
| ef23a23d-5e2c-42a0-952b-cf43732c55b8 | 6317 | Juice |
| ef23a23d-5e2c-42a0-952b-cf43732c55b8 | 6941 | Chips |
| 0fb69525-7b71-4dec-ab77-36a698d519f6 | 5425 | Wrap |
| 59b5f8e9-96f1-483b-a31d-659492765e06 | 7233 | Smoothie |
| 59b5f8e9-96f1-483b-a31d-659492765e06 | 3803 | Water |
| 59b5f8e9-96f1-483b-a31d-659492765e06 | 7961 | Salad |
| d8656ba2-4076-4036-9515-6fea1f9e58d4 | 7961 | Salad |
| d8656ba2-4076-4036-9515-6fea1f9e58d4 | 5425 | Wrap |

The main thing giving me trouble is the varying number of nested json elements. My initial instinct was that I could do something like `to_json()` ->`json.loads()`->`json_normalize`, but I can't make that work with the `order_guid` and the multiple selections. Looping seems silly. It *feels* like this is a simple enough problem that someone else should've encountered it, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899005/how-to-flatten-a-pandas-dataframe-with-some-columns-as-json) is the closest I've seen to the issue.

Is there a pandas method for this? Or something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Why do some selection items have `id` and others `guid`?

Comment: Are values in the `selections` column a list of dicts or JSON?

Comment: @Nick Looks like they're strings based on how they're formatted, plus OP said "json strings" in the title.

Comment: Related: [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](/q/38231591/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use `df.explode()` before using `json_normalize()`. Hope this is what you meant.

```py
df = df.explode('selections').reset_index(drop=True)
result_df = pd.concat([df['order_guid'], pd.json_normalize(df.selections)], axis=1)
result_df['guid'] = result_df['guid'].fillna(result_df['id'])
result_df = result_df[['order_guid', 'guid', 'item']].rename(columns={'guid': 'selection_guid', 'item': 'selection_item'})
```

Comment: `df.explode` did the trick, though the rest of my code varied a bit, but it worked out for me so I'm sticking with it.

```df = df.explode('checks.selections').reset_index(drop=True)
    df_json = df.to_json(orient="records")
    df_load = json.loads(df_json)
    df_normalized = pd.json_normalize(df_load)```

Thanks for your help! You spared me a (longer) headache.

Comment: Update: The code in my first comment worked*, but I actually ended up using just the first _two_ lines of your code. I must've made some error when trying to implement it the first time. 

* I just realized that this left out a critical part of the request; the `order_guid`