# Create a DataFrame from a heavily nested JSON in Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a deeply nested JSON file taken from IBM's personality analysis tool. What is the shortest way I can create a DataFrame out of it. **It doesn't matter if the parent "key" is repeated in multiple rows**. I can use multi indexing to make it look good. My primary concern is to make spread out the JSON into a dataframe. Here is the link to the JSON: https://api.myjson.com/bins/vmdaf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Consider providing a small but reproducible sample JSON data set and a desired DF. Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

The json_normalize function is most likely what can help you out most here.

```
 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

 df = json_normalize(my_json_blob)
```

Comment: It does split the json with respect to the tier 1 of its hierarchy, thanks. But the json that I have has 2 more level to go.