# Pandas read JSON into Excel

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to parse JSON data from an URL. I have fetched the data and parsed it into a dataframe. From the looks of it, I am missing a step.

Data Returns in JSON format in excel but my data frame returns two columns: entry number and JSON Text

```
import urllib.request
import json
import pandas
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gavinr/usa-
mcdonalds-locations/master/mcdonalds.geojson") as url:
data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
print(data)
json_parsed = json.dumps(data)
print(json_parsed)

df=pandas.read_json(json_parsed)
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('Mcdonaldsstorelist.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: My data frame returns two columns: entry number and Json Text -> See below
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-80.140924, 25.789141]}, 'properties': {'storeNumber': '14372', 'playplace': 'N', 'storeUrl': 'http://www.mcflorida.com/14372', 'address': '1601 ALTON RD', 'driveThru': 'Y', 'phone': '(305)672-7055', 'storeType': 'FREESTANDING', 'freeWifi': 'Y', 'city': 'MIAMI BEACH', 'archCard': 'Y', 'state': 'FL', 'zip': '33139-2420'}, 'type': 'Feature'}

I am looking to parse out each field into separate columns

Comment: Then parsing from the URL is not the problem. Pandas is

Comment: Have you tried printing the Dataframe itself? You can debug your code without Excel

Comment: yeah, printing the DF has the same results. Gives me the JSON string in the second column with no separation

Comment: Also, `json_parsed` is really not necessary. `json.loads` is what parses the JSON string. Putting it back into a string using `dumps` shouldn't be required

Comment: See if you missed something from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Looks like I have to flatten arrays inside the string, I have been googling some techniques. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use *`json_normalize`*:

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['features'])
```

---

```
df.head()

      geometry.coordinates geometry.type    properties.address  \
0  [-80.140924, 25.789141]         Point         1601 ALTON RD   
1  [-80.218683, 25.765501]         Point        1400 SW 8TH ST   
2  [-80.185108, 25.849872]         Point    8116 BISCAYNE BLVD   
3   [-80.37197, 25.550894]         Point    23351 SW 112TH AVE   
4   [-80.36734, 25.579132]         Point  10855 CARIBBEAN BLVD   

  properties.archCard properties.city properties.driveThru  \
0                   Y     MIAMI BEACH                    Y   
1                   Y           MIAMI                    Y   
2                   Y           MIAMI                    Y   
3                   N       HOMESTEAD                    Y   
4                   Y           MIAMI                    Y   

  properties.freeWifi properties.phone properties.playplace properties.state  \
0                   Y    (305)672-7055                    N               FL   
1                   Y    (305)285-0974                    Y               FL   
2                   Y    (305)756-0400                    N               FL   
3                   Y    (305)258-7837                    N               FL   
4                   Y    (305)254-3487                    Y               FL   

  properties.storeNumber properties.storeType             properties.storeUrl  \
0                  14372         FREESTANDING  http://www.mcflorida.com/14372   
1                   7408         FREESTANDING   http://www.mcflorida.com/7408   
2                  11511         FREESTANDING  http://www.mcflorida.com/11511   
3                  34014         FREESTANDING                             NaN   
4                  12215         FREESTANDING  http://www.mcflorida.com/12215   

  properties.zip     type  
0     33139-2420  Feature  
1          33135  Feature  
2          33138  Feature  
3          33032  Feature  
4          33157  Feature  

df.columns

Index(['geometry.coordinates', 'geometry.type', 'properties.address',
       'properties.archCard', 'properties.city', 'properties.driveThru',
       'properties.freeWifi', 'properties.phone', 'properties.playplace',
       'properties.state', 'properties.storeNumber', 'properties.storeType',
       'properties.storeUrl', 'properties.zip', 'type'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I actually indexed it just like you did without seeing your answer! Thank you for all the help