# JSON list items to dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using an API that has changed its spec and now my JSON feed is slightly different.

BEFORE:

```
{"code":2000,"message":"SUCCESS","data":
    {"1":
        {"id":1,
        "name":"Amanda",
        "score":"57.36%",
        "average":"53.47%"
        }
     }
}
```

Then, I used something to this effect:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

jsonfile = 'file.json'
with open(jsonfile) as j:
  data = json.load(j)
  rows = [v for k, v in data["data"].items()]

  df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['id', 'name', 'score', 'average'])
```

---

Source AFTER:

```
{"status":"success","code":0,"data":
    {"data":
        [
            {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Robert",
            "score":"48.85%",
            "average":"40.52%"
             }
         ]
     }
}
```

So I'm attempting to adjust using some of the resources:

- [Convert JSON list to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838743/convert-json-list-to-pandas-dataframe)
- [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)
- [how to convert json data with list of list to dataframe using python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355667/how-to-convert-json-data-with-list-of-list-to-dataframe-using-python-pandas)

What I've tried so far:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

jsonfile = 'file.json'
with open(jsonfile) as j:
  data = json.load(j)

  df = json_normalize(data, ['data'])
```

I've also tried:
`df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)`

I get the following:

```
TypeError: {....} for path data. Must be list or null.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Correction:

When using this method:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687857/python-json-list-to-pandas-dataframe

I get the following output:
```
Dataframe:    code                                               data   status
0     0  [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Robert', 'score': '48.92%', 'a...  success
1     0                                            success

```

Comment: `json_normalize(data, ['data', 'data'])`.  the `data` is wrapped in `data`, so your record_path should require 1 more 'data'.

Comment: Yep, that was it.