# Python Pandas dataframe from json conversion problem

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I've got a problem reading a json-file to pandas dataframe. I've got a largish json-file with structure like this:

```
`{"name":
         [{"header": -999.0,
           "header2": -999.0,
           "header3": -999.0,
            .....
           "headern": -999.0},
            .....
            .....

           {"header": -999.0,
           "header2": -999.0,
           "header3": -999.0}],
 "name2":
           [{"header": -999.0,
           "header2": -999.0,
           "header3": -999.0,
            .....
           "headern": -999.0},
            .....
            .....

           {"header": -999.0,
           "header2": -999.0,
           "header3": -999.0,]}
```

As expected `data = pd.read_json(source,orient='index',lines=True)` reads the file so that "names" are indexes and the headers and values to one single column per row. I would like the table to be in this form:

```
    header1 header2 ... header n
 0   -999   -999          -999
 1   -999   -999          -999
 2   -999   -999          -999
```

I tried to loop through the file with codes like this (and many others)

```
import pandas as pd


for index, row in data.iterrows():             
    df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row), ignore_index=True)
```

But I cannot get the correct structure (e.g. the example above gives empty df). I am new to python&pandas so I probably don't have proper understanding of dataframes, but after reading documentations multiple times I still couldn't figure this out.

Comment: Follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe
It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution (intially reading the file into an array) from the link above.