# Convert a field content to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image]

The field '_source' has a JSON structure in the content. I'd like to convert this field in another dataframe with the correspondent columns.

The type of this field is Series:

```
type(df['_source']) 
   pandas.core.series.Series
```

Which is the best way to convert this field ('_source') in a Pandas DataFrame?

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Comment: Finally this post help me to solve what I want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use these lines of code to convert '_source' in correspondent columns:

```
subdf= df['_source'].apply(json.loads)
pd.DataFrame(subdf.tolist())
```