# reading json data into DataFrame

Tags: python, json, dataframe, twitter

I'm having a problem with some json file (generated from Twython / Tweeter API).

The file looks like this:

```
[
{
    "created_at": "Thu Mar 14 20:24:53 +0000 2019",
    "id": 1106290123426140165,
    "id_str": "1106290123426140165",
    "text": "RT @ALABDULLATIF: n@B_Al3bdullatif \n\u278b\u2026",
    "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" 
     rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 1091414851400929286,
        "id_str": "1091414851400929286",
        "name": "u064a",
        "screen_name": "UThbZ4nwsuzAMQm",
        "location": null,
        "url": null,
        "description": null,
        "translator_type": "none",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 0,
        "friends_count": 0,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "statuses_count": 2,
        "created_at": "Fri Feb 01 19:15:52 +0000 2019",
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        ETC
```

When I try to read it with this:

```
fname = "tweets_03.json" 

text=[]
retweets=[]
language=[]
followers=[]

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.isspace():
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            text.append(tweet.get('text', ''))
            retweets.append(tweet.get('retweet_count',''))
            language.append(tweet.get('lang',''))
            followers.append(tweet.get('followers_count',''))

text=pd.DataFrame(text)
text.columns=['text']
retweets=pd.DataFrame(retweets)
retweets.columns=['retweets']
language=pd.DataFrame(language)
language.columns=['language']
followers=pd.DataFrame(followers)
followers.columns=['followers']

df=pd.concat([text,retweets,language,followers],axis=1)
df.head(5)
```

I get the following error msg:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

I also tried:

```
data = "tweets_03.json" 
jdata = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(jdata)
```

and that gives me the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

If anyone could pse help it would be much appreciated. I'm wanting to convert the data into a dataframe.
Thank you
Best Wishes

Comment: Duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: when i try the above  (# reading the JSON data using json.load()
file = 'data.json'
with open(file) as train_file:
    dict_train = json.load(train_file)

# converting json dataset from dictionary to dataframe
train = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_train, orient='index')
train.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True) , I now get the following error msg: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1938 column 2 (char 79714)

Comment: ... and when i check the content of line 1938, I see this: ][

Comment: @tezzaaa I have updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: Hi, i get the following error: ValueError: Expected object or value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your json file is actually multiple json files into 1. You need to separate them and load read them in.

The way I did that was find all those `][` instances and split on those. Then just iterate through each of those to be loaded and then dumped into a dataframe. It is quite messy though as it's nested dictionaries and lists within there. But this will generate a dataframe for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = []
with open('tweets_03.json') as json_file:  
    data_str = json_file.read()
    data_str = data_str.split('[',1)[-1]
    data_str = data_str.rsplit(']',1)[0]
    data_str = data_str.split('][')

for jsonStr in data_str:
    jsonStr = '[' + jsonStr + ']'

    temp_data = json.loads(jsonStr)
    for each in temp_data:
        data.append(each)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
    contributors                        ...                                                                       user
0           None                        ...                          {'id': 427643942, 'id_str': '427643942', 'name...
1           None                        ...                          {'id': 1063556070151528449, 'id_str': '1063556...
2           None                        ...                          {'id': 924769730606567424, 'id_str': '92476973...
3           None                        ...                          {'id': 287355962, 'id_str': '287355962', 'name...
4           None                        ...                          {'id': 2908153155, 'id_str': '2908153155', 'na...
5           None                        ...                          {'id': 1040181804026744832, 'id_str': '1040181...
6           None                        ...                          {'id': 397901665, 'id_str': '397901665', 'name...
7           None                        ...                          {'id': 14547327, 'id_str': '14547327', 'name':...
8           None                        ...                          {'id': 1159572698, 'id_str': '1159572698', 'na...
9           None                        ...                          {'id': 3025332991, 'id_str': '3025332991', 'na...
10          None                        ...                          {'id': 926921371065647104, 'id_str': '92692137...
11          None                        ...                          {'id': 428415680, 'id_str': '428415680', 'name...
12          None                        ...                          {'id': 1040967562442551301, 'id_str': '1040967...
13          None                        ...                          {'id': 984957304905744385, 'id_str': '98495730...
14          None                        ...                          {'id': 24174895, 'id_str': '24174895', 'name':...
15          None                        ...                          {'id': 543254812, 'id_str': '543254812', 'name...
16          None                        ...                          {'id': 377146136, 'id_str': '377146136', 'name...
17          None                        ...                          {'id': 63308004, 'id_str': '63308004', 'name':...
18          None                        ...                          {'id': 3039612566, 'id_str': '3039612566', 'na...
19          None                        ...                          {'id': 2902946418, 'id_str': '2902946418', 'na...
20          None                        ...                          {'id': 966776807830716416, 'id_str': '96677680...
21          None                        ...                          {'id': 1017086923507040256, 'id_str': '1017086...
22          None                        ...                          {'id': 888271500658081792, 'id_str': '88827150...
23          None                        ...                          {'id': 1085986810591932419, 'id_str': '1085986...
24          None                        ...                          {'id': 720061374999568384, 'id_str': '72006137...
25          None                        ...                          {'id': 21243436, 'id_str': '21243436', 'name':...
26          None                        ...                          {'id': 2849771796, 'id_str': '2849771796', 'na...
27          None                        ...                          {'id': 790823048744165376, 'id_str': '79082304...
28          None                        ...                          {'id': 881673927927496704, 'id_str': '88167392...
29          None                        ...                          {'id': 4344166641, 'id_str': '4344166641', 'na...
..           ...                        ...                                                                        ...
942         None                        ...                          {'id': 306237570, 'id_str': '306237570', 'name...
943         None                        ...                          {'id': 883298986739748864, 'id_str': '88329898...
944         None                        ...                          {'id': 3027274443, 'id_str': '3027274443', 'na...
945         None                        ...                          {'id': 3189578162, 'id_str': '3189578162', 'na...
946         None                        ...                          {'id': 2327121601, 'id_str': '2327121601', 'na...
947         None                        ...                          {'id': 990411876, 'id_str': '990411876', 'name...
948         None                        ...                          {'id': 2995641808, 'id_str': '2995641808', 'na...
949         None                        ...                          {'id': 44540580, 'id_str': '44540580', 'name':...
950         None                        ...                          {'id': 47636922, 'id_str': '47636922', 'name':...
951         None                        ...                          {'id': 996052119433048064, 'id_str': '99605211...
952         None                        ...                          {'id': 806255305474641920, 'id_str': '80625530...
953         None                        ...                          {'id': 66738256, 'id_str': '66738256', 'name':...
954         None                        ...                          {'id': 1068149370229542912, 'id_str': '1068149...
955         None                        ...                          {'id': 229965328, 'id_str': '229965328', 'name...
956         None                        ...                          {'id': 1039247810410016769, 'id_str': '1039247...
957         None                        ...                          {'id': 4886141236, 'id_str': '4886141236', 'na...
958         None                        ...                          {'id': 892138074, 'id_str': '892138074', 'name...
959         None                        ...                          {'id': 134945640, 'id_str': '134945640', 'name...
960         None                        ...                          {'id': 300694818, 'id_str': '300694818', 'name...
961         None                        ...                          {'id': 840240258, 'id_str': '840240258', 'name...
962         None                        ...                          {'id': 265481826, 'id_str': '265481826', 'name...
963         None                        ...                          {'id': 1082113676344098816, 'id_str': '1082113...
964         None                        ...                          {'id': 229965328, 'id_str': '229965328', 'name...
965         None                        ...                          {'id': 4634960663, 'id_str': '4634960663', 'na...
966         None                        ...                          {'id': 161350829, 'id_str': '161350829', 'name...
967         None                        ...                          {'id': 1003363328641716225, 'id_str': '1003363...
968         None                        ...                          {'id': 898601924630597636, 'id_str': '89860192...
969         None                        ...                          {'id': 3285036854, 'id_str': '3285036854', 'na...
970         None                        ...                          {'id': 1099846021952294912, 'id_str': '1099846...
971         None                        ...                          {'id': 34326169, 'id_str': '34326169', 'name':...

[972 rows x 36 columns]
```

Comment: Hi, I get the following error: ValueError: Trailing data

Comment: THANK YOU CHITOWN88 :-)  YOU SAVED MY DAY

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

fileName = 'tweets_03.json'
jsonData = pd.read_json(fileName,lines=True)
```