# transferring JSON to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

I am trying to read some data from two json files, and find the users with the same name and then get the values of the specific key from them, however, I had an issue with one of them (data_bvp) that has 100 rows and 1 column in a list. 
when I saved the data frame as a csv file the, I have got this 
[image]

The first json file looks like this:

```
{ "Name": "Alex" :["bvp":[1,2,3], "gsr":[3,2,1] ] } , { "Name": "Laura" :["bvp":[2,3,4], "gsr":[3,2,1] ] }
```

The secon jason file has the following elements:

```
{ "Name" : "Alex" : ["calm" :0 , "tension":1] }, { "Name": "Laura" : ["calm":1, "tesnion":0}
```

I am gonig to get the data that has the same name to get the values of bvp and tension from each json file and save it as a csv file.

it seems that data does not save in the right format like [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
I can see the list looks like this : [1,2,3 , [2,3,4

actually, my final dataset would look like this :

```
 name   col1 col2 col3 tension
  Alex   1   2    3    1
  Laura  2   3    4    0
```

Do you have any idea what part of my code has a problem? 
Thank you!

```
with open('raw_data-export.json') as data_file:
    data_bvp = json.loads(data_file.read())
arr_b = list(data_bvp.keys())

with open('v2-1-data-export.json') as data_file_2:
    data_tension = json.loads(data_file_2.read())
arr_tension = list(data_tension.keys())

matches =[]
for i in arr_b:
    for j in arr_tension:
        if i == j:
            matches.append(i)
print("MATCHES", matches)


bvps = []
tension = []

for b in matches:
    bvps.append(data_bvp[b]['bvp'])
       # PROBLEM 

for t in matches:
    tension.append(data_tension[t]['pre']['tense'])



bvp_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(bvps)
bvp_data_frame.to_csv('./bvp.csv')
```

Comment: Without a sample of your json files, is difficult to answer

Comment: Edit you question to add a sample. Few lines of each json are enough, just be sure that using you code we can see the problem

Comment: data_b in the second line has to data_bvp , right?

Comment: @JissRaphel yes! I edited the question

Comment: you can just json_load and use json_normalize() from pandas.io.json. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: The json you've posted does not seem well formatted

Answer (score 1):

I created the test DataFrames as follows:

```
t1 = '''[
    {"Name": "Alex",  "bvp": [1,2,3], "gsr": [3,2,1]},
    {"Name": "Laura", "bvp": [2,3,4], "gsr": [3,2,1]} ]'''
df1 = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(t1))    
t2 = '''[
    {"Name": "Alex",  "calm": 0, "tension": 1},
    {"Name": "Laura", "calm": 1, "tension": 0} ]'''
df2 = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(t2))
```

(slightly changed, as your original JSON string resulted in an error).

The first step is to create a work DataFrame - a break of `bvp` column
into separate columns, with original index:

```
wrk = pd.DataFrame(df1.bvp.tolist(), index=df1.index,
    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

The result is:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     2     3     4
```

And to get the final result, run:

```
df1.join(wrk).drop(columns=['bvp', 'gsr']).merge(df2, on='Name')
```

Note the sequence of operations:

- First *df1* is joined with *wrk* (on the index).
- Then *bvp* and *gsr* columns are dropped.
- And finally the result is *merge*d with *df2* (on *Name*).