# Turning JSON into dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to get a data frame but keep running into various error messages depending on the arguments I specify in read.json after I specify my file.

I've run through many of the arguments in the pandas.read_json documentation, but haven't been able to identify a solution.

```
import pandas
json_file = "https://gis.fema.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NSS/OpenShelters/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&outSR=4326&f=json"
pandas.read_json(json_file)
```

I'm trying to get a data frame but keep running into various error messages depending on the arguments I specify in read.json after I specify my file.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe
I think your task looks similar to this one!

Answer (score 1):

Because the JSON is not directly convertible to `DataFrame`. `read_json` works only with a few formats defined by the [`orient` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html). Your JSON doesn't follow any of the allowed formats so you need to manipulate the JSON before converting it to a data frame.

Let's take a high level look at your JSON:

```
{
    "displayFieldName": ...,
    "fieldAliases": {...},
    "fields": {...},
    "features": [...]
}
```

I'm gonna fathom a guess and assume the `features` node is what you want. Let's div deeper into `features`:

```
"features": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1,
            "SHELTER_ID": 223259,
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 2,
            "SHELTER_ID": 223331,
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

`features` contains a list of objects, each having an `attributes` node. The data contained in the `attributes` node is what you actually want.

Here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

json_file = "https://gis.fema.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NSS/OpenShelters/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&outSR=4326&f=json"
data = urlopen(json_file).read()
raw_json = json.loads(data)
formatted_json = [feature['attributes'] for feature in raw_json['features']]
```

`formatted_json` is now a list of dictionaries containing the data we are after. It is no longer JSON. To create the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(formatted_json)
```

Comment: This works, but now I am having issues with the proxy. I've tried mapping my proxies and then feeding it as a parameter to urlopen(), but that's only for Python 2. I tried working with ProxyHandler but couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: The network is a separate issue from the programming one. I can't help with that, sorry :(