# Read json from BI Query

Tags: json, pandas

I have BI Query service which returns something like this:

```
{"count":78,
"next":"...",
"previous":null,
"results":[
    {"name":"John"surname":"Smith"},
    {"name":"Bob"surname":"Black"},
]}
```

Is there any easy method to read this data to Pandas DataFrame? read_json(url) can not deal with this. Of course, I can write my code for this, but I believe that it is a common task and someone has written code for this.

Comment: do you want to create a dataframe from the results?

Comment: Yes, I want to create DF for all results (iterate until next!=null)

Comment: I think this guy had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe
and found a nice solution for it

Comment: I have created a task for it on Pandas: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28877