# converting nested json into tabular format using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python. I have json file with many record and I want to convert that into tabular format. a sample of json data is show here. all records follows similar structure.
Below is sample json file. for simplicity I kept only two records.I am looking for a generic solution that I can use for files having different data.
json file -->[{
    'asset':{'id':'123'},
    'topvol':[{'a':'x','b':{'c':'cc','d':'dd'},'cxt':[{'m':'n'},{'m':'nn'}]},{'a':'x','b':{'c':'cc','d':'dd'},'cxt':[{'m':'n'},{'m':'nn'}]}]
},{
    'asset':{'id':'124'},
    'topvol':[{'a':'x','b':{'c':'cc','d':'dd'},'cxt':[{'m':'n'},{'m':'nn'}]},{'a':'x','b':{'c':'cc','d':'dd'},'cxt':[{'m':'n'},{'m':'nn'}]}]
}]

expected output: this is just for one record.asset.id 124 will have similar output.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: no. I am looking for a generic solution that can be used for other file having different data