# How do I properly unwrap this json response in Python to get the data I need into a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, pandas

So, I'm working with Cisco Prime Infrastructure's API and I'm at the end of my rope. The script I'm writing is supposed to take a report from its getReport operation, decode it (not sure if that's the right word), and put it into a Pandas DataFrame. The problem is, there's junk wrapped around it. Here's an example of the response json:

```
{
  "mgmtResponse" : {
    "@requestUrl" : "https://localhost/webacs/api/v4/op/reportService/getReport?reportTitle=MyReport",
    "@responseType" : "operation",
    "@rootUrl" : "https://localhost/webacs/api/v4/op",
    "reportDataDTO" : [ {
      "childReports" : {
        "childReport" : [ ]
      },
      "dataRows" : {
        "dataRow" : [ {
          "entries" : {
            "entry" : [ {
              "attributeName" : "String value",
              "dataValue" : "String value",
              "displayName" : "String value"
            }, {
              "attributeName" : "Another string value",
              "dataValue" : "Another string value",
              "displayName" : "Another string value"
            } ]
          }
        }, {
          "entries" : {
            "entry" : [ {
              "attributeName" : "String value",
              "dataValue" : "String value",
              "displayName" : "String value"
            }, {
              "attributeName" : "Another string value",
              "dataValue" : "Another string value",
              "displayName" : "Another string value"
            } ]
          }
        } ]
      },
      "descriptorName" : "String value",
      "pageCount" : 15,
      "pageIndex" : 15,
      "reportDate" : "String value",
      "reportName" : "String value",
      "reportTitle" : "String value",
      "reportUrl" : "String value"
    } ]
  }
}
```

I want my script to only use the information nested under "dataRows", but I can't figure out what to do. So far I have this:

```
response = rq.get(url, auth=(cpi_user,cpi_password), verify=False, timeout = 300)
    print(response.status_code)

    if (response.status_code == rq.codes.ok):
        responseJSON = response.json()
        rogue_ap_flatten = json_normalize(responseJSON)
        print (rogue_ap_flatten)
        rogues = pd.DataFrame(rogue_ap_flatten)
        print(rogues.head(50))
        return rogues
```

And all I get in return is:

```
                               mgmtResponse.@requestUrl  ...                         mgmtResponse.reportDataDTO
    0  https://prime/webacs/api/v4/op/reportS...  ...  [{'childReports': {'childReport': []}, 'dataRo...

[1 rows x 4 columns]
```

I've tried using just the .text method from requests, I've tried using another json flattening library (json_flatten) with the option to exclude certain keys, and I'm considering just using sed in python somehow. It doesn't need to work for other reports, just one, so I have some leeway to specify any specific keys or whatnot. How would y'all tackle this problem?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get to just the `dataRows` stuff using something like this:

```py
import json
data = {<your data>}
print(json.dumps(result['mgmtResponse']['reportDataDTO'][0]['dataRows'], indent=4))
```

**Output**

```
{
    "dataRow": [
        {
            "entries": {
                "entry": [
                    {
                        "attributeName": "String value",
                        "dataValue": "String value",
                        "displayName": "String value"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributeName": "Another string value",
                        "dataValue": "Another string value",
                        "displayName": "Another string value"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "entries": {
                "entry": [
                    {
                        "attributeName": "String value",
                        "dataValue": "String value",
                        "displayName": "String value"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributeName": "Another string value",
                        "dataValue": "Another string value",
                        "displayName": "Another string value"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. It just seems you are a bit confused by the format of your json response, I tried to address the structure I see below, but just take a careful look at how everything is nested.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
req_session = requests.Session()
response = req_session.get('<url>')
df.append(response.json()['mgmtResponse']['reportDataDTO'][0]['dataRows'])
```

Answer (score 0):

my assumption that is you want to build a panda DF based on the incoming values. json.loads could help because "object_hook" can be used to provide custom deserializations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json


def filter_cols(element):
    # deal with each dataRow and build your the structure that will get into the data frame
    return {
        element['attributeName']: element['dataValue'],
    }



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # from api response
    # content = json.loads(response.text)

    # doing this because I have your data in a file
    with open("data.json", "r") as read_file:
        content = json.load(read_file)

    f = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        json.loads(json.dumps(content['mgmtResponse']['reportDataDTO'][0]['dataRows']), object_hook=filter_cols))
```

Answer (score 0):

If response has only one format then proposed previously solution `result['mgmtResponse']['reportDataDTO'][0]['dataRows']` would suffice.
But if your responses differ but you could establish some rules like e.g. response json contains useful `dataRows` data only in nested dict's or lists then you could write some util method to recursively search for it.

Example code:

```
def search_for_dataRows(data):
    if "dataRows" in data.keys():
        return data["dataRows"]
    else:
        result = None
        for value in data.values():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                result = search_for_dataRows(value)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for list_item in value:
                    if isinstance(list_item, dict):
                        result = search_for_dataRows(list_item)
            if result:
                return result
        return None

response_json = response.json()
search_result = search_for_dataRows(response_json)
```