# The error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'" appears when I try to convert JSON to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dict data(import from JSON) as follows and would like to change it into Pandas Dataframe like below.

```
date            value        profit
01/06/2020        0        0
01/07/202        0.42        12.59
......            ......        ......
......            ......        ......
```

Step 1 original data

d_gain

```
{'error': False, 'message': '', 'dailyGain': [[{'date': '01/06/2020', 'value': 0, 'profit': 0}], [{'date': '01/07/2020', 'value': 0.42, 'profit': 12.59}], [{'date': '01/08/2020', 'value': -14.49, 'profit': -447.42}], [{'date': '01/09/2020', 'value': -12.47, 'profit': 362.38}], [{'date': '01/10/2020', 'value': -12.6, 'profit': -4.28}]]}
```

Step 2

In; d_gain2 = d_gain['dailyGain']

Out;

```
<class 'list'>

[[{'date': '01/06/2020', 'value': 0, 'profit': 0}], [{'date': '01/07/2020', 'value': 0.42, 'profit': 12.59}], [{'date': '01/08/2020', 'value': -14.49, 'profit': -447.42}], [{'date': '01/09/2020', 'value': -12.47, 'profit': 362.38}], [{'date': '01/10/2020', 'value': -12.6, 'profit': -4.28}]]
```

Then I try to convert to DataFrame, but the error appears,

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Please help me to sort this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of list enclosing each of the dictionary.

It can be

- Multiple dictionaries with matching keys enclosed by a list.
- A dictionary with keys as columns and values in the form of list.

Can you try a different approach?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d_gain2 = [[{'date': '01/06/2020', 'value': 0, 'profit': 0}], [{'date': '01/07/2020', 'value': 0.42, 'profit': 12.59}], [{'date': '01/08/2020', 'value': -14.49, 'profit': -447.42}], [{'date': '01/09/2020', 'value': -12.47, 'profit': 362.38}], [{'date': '01/10/2020', 'value': -12.6, 'profit': -4.28}]]
>>> df_skel = list()
>>> for item in d_gain2:
...     df_skel.append(item[0])
... 
>>> dataset = pd.DataFrame(df_skel)
>>> dataset
         date  profit  value
0  01/06/2020    0.00   0.00
1  01/07/2020   12.59   0.42
2  01/08/2020 -447.42 -14.49
3  01/09/2020  362.38 -12.47
4  01/10/2020   -4.28 -12.60
```

Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Dear

Thanks so much! It worked. I learned a lot.

Have a wonderful day too!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this worked for me.

normalized_dict = pd.json_normalize(your_dict, sep=',') # separate by commans instead of period in case it is going into a list or use any separator you need

your_dict_pd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(normalized_dict)