# Converting JSON to CSV - Python

Tags: python, json, excel, csv

I am trying to convert my json data to csv/excel file. I have tried many links but I am not able to do so.
My json data is

```
{
  "5-38-23pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.963812,
    "Energy": 450448,
    "Current": 0.411698,
    "Frequency": 49.92297,
    "Voltage": 233.4855,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 18.73749,
      "Active Power": 67.74399,
      "Apparent Power": 70.28757
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-28-30pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 450209,
    "Current": 0.694866,
    "Frequency": 49.96407,
    "Voltage": 233.7949,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 116.3057,
      "Apparent Power": 116.3057
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-20-30pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.979241,
    "Energy": 452038,
    "Current": 0.357428,
    "Frequency": 49.94864,
    "Voltage": 228.5169,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 12.18204,
      "Active Power": 58.85109,
      "Apparent Power": 60.09869
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-41-26pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.982096,
    "Energy": 451434,
    "Current": 0.37199,
    "Frequency": 49.98662,
    "Voltage": 229.8291,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 11.51948,
      "Active Power": 60.05545,
      "Apparent Power": 61.15026
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-30-01pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 450263,
    "Current": 0.699439,
    "Frequency": 50.06778,
    "Voltage": 234.8081,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 114.5423,
      "Apparent Power": 114.5423
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-30-41pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 450282,
    "Current": 0.706373,
    "Frequency": 50.08531,
    "Voltage": 234.4807,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 115.3131,
      "Apparent Power": 115.3131
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-56-53pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 453397,
    "Current": 0.780276,
    "Frequency": 50.09162,
    "Voltage": 231.0131,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 168.4044,
      "Apparent Power": 168.4044
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-03-04pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.98258,
    "Energy": 451772,
    "Current": 0.364989,
    "Frequency": 50.02618,
    "Voltage": 228.8585,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 11.2622,
      "Active Power": 59.54502,
      "Apparent Power": 60.60071
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-31-22pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 452322,
    "Current": 0.762901,
    "Frequency": 50.00087,
    "Voltage": 229.1156,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": -6.920631,
      "Active Power": 163.9421,
      "Apparent Power": 164.0881
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-32-55pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.968951,
    "Energy": 451313,
    "Current": 0.373791,
    "Frequency": 50.02784,
    "Voltage": 231.0016,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 15.15752,
      "Active Power": 59.40047,
      "Apparent Power": 61.30388
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-35-12pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.957514,
    "Energy": 450397,
    "Current": 0.408113,
    "Frequency": 49.96738,
    "Voltage": 234.5096,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 19.65847,
      "Active Power": 65.27112,
      "Apparent Power": 68.16725
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-47-53pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.96431,
    "Energy": 450611,
    "Current": 0.4033,
    "Frequency": 50.01154,
    "Voltage": 233.571,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 17.84743,
      "Active Power": 65.00044,
      "Apparent Power": 67.40614
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-48-07pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 453053,
    "Current": 0.767276,
    "Frequency": 50.00126,
    "Voltage": 229.629,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": -6.818354,
      "Active Power": 164.6067,
      "Apparent Power": 164.7478
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-29-23pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 450246,
    "Current": 0.706648,
    "Frequency": 50.02319,
    "Voltage": 234.3504,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 116.6343,
      "Apparent Power": 116.6343
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-27-42pm": {
    "Power Factor": -0.998596,
    "Energy": 452181,
    "Current": 0.780348,
    "Frequency": 49.98395,
    "Voltage": 228.3724,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": -8.841948,
      "Active Power": 166.6973,
      "Apparent Power": 166.9316
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-56-20pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.980369,
    "Energy": 451665,
    "Current": 0.367398,
    "Frequency": 49.85281,
    "Voltage": 228.2693,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 11.96138,
      "Active Power": 59.47347,
      "Apparent Power": 60.6644
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-00-59pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.984718,
    "Energy": 451740,
    "Current": 0.369186,
    "Frequency": 49.97466,
    "Voltage": 228.0429,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 10.59825,
      "Active Power": 59.92554,
      "Apparent Power": 60.85551
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-40-04pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.968153,
    "Energy": 450478,
    "Current": 0.404456,
    "Frequency": 49.95207,
    "Voltage": 233.4114,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 16.98559,
      "Active Power": 65.68439,
      "Apparent Power": 67.84503
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-22-22pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.967638,
    "Energy": 451150,
    "Current": 0.371291,
    "Frequency": 50.04655,
    "Voltage": 231.8856,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 15.92136,
      "Active Power": 61.05223,
      "Apparent Power": 63.09409
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-48-51pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 674463400000.0,
    "Current": 0.756341,
    "Frequency": 49.99725,
    "Voltage": 230.5815,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 162.9217,
      "Apparent Power": 162.9217
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-21-54pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0,
    "Energy": 0,
    "Current": 0,
    "Frequency": 0,
    "Voltage": 0,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 0,
      "Apparent Power": 0
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-38-30pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 452629,
    "Current": 0.769659,
    "Frequency": 49.9932,
    "Voltage": 228.7356,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": -6.62216,
      "Active Power": 165.1055,
      "Apparent Power": 165.2383
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-57-20pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 453441,
    "Current": 0.777093,
    "Frequency": 50.04037,
    "Voltage": 231.5875,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 168.3309,
      "Apparent Power": 168.3309
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-55-00pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.969612,
    "Energy": 450727,
    "Current": 0.378488,
    "Frequency": 50.01944,
    "Voltage": 232.4185,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 15.16312,
      "Active Power": 60.0955,
      "Apparent Power": 61.97894
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-43-04pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.963948,
    "Energy": 450527,
    "Current": 0.393088,
    "Frequency": 49.97508,
    "Voltage": 233.0034,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 17.52854,
      "Active Power": 63.49887,
      "Apparent Power": 65.87379
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "11-17-31am": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 443846,
    "Current": 0.694069,
    "Frequency": 49.91456,
    "Voltage": 233.9931,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 118.8176,
      "Apparent Power": 118.8176
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-37-06pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.963233,
    "Energy": 450429,
    "Current": 0.400825,
    "Frequency": 49.94184,
    "Voltage": 234.0396,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 18.02823,
      "Active Power": 64.63525,
      "Apparent Power": 67.1024
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "8-07-49pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 28368,
    "Current": 0.775525,
    "Frequency": 50.03774,
    "Voltage": 232.9772,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 168.7114,
      "Apparent Power": 168.7114
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-35-34pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.954589,
    "Energy": 450408,
    "Current": 0.406308,
    "Frequency": 49.94038,
    "Voltage": 234.548,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 20.55201,
      "Active Power": 65.85101,
      "Apparent Power": 68.98363
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-58-49pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.981298,
    "Energy": 451707,
    "Current": 0.362586,
    "Frequency": 49.92701,
    "Voltage": 228.5928,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 11.66225,
      "Active Power": 59.45097,
      "Apparent Power": 60.58403
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-56-00pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.980369,
    "Energy": 451665,
    "Current": 0.367398,
    "Frequency": 49.85281,
    "Voltage": 228.2693,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 11.96138,
      "Active Power": 59.47347,
      "Apparent Power": 60.6644
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-55-15pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.980906,
    "Energy": 451642,
    "Current": 0.366826,
    "Frequency": 49.8881,
    "Voltage": 228.3533,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 11.7303,
      "Active Power": 59.16306,
      "Apparent Power": 60.31474
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-52-30pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.981264,
    "Energy": 451611,
    "Current": 0.372072,
    "Frequency": 49.8423,
    "Voltage": 228.0021,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 11.65271,
      "Active Power": 59.34711,
      "Apparent Power": 60.48029
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-53-08pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.96978,
    "Energy": 450697,
    "Current": 0.400942,
    "Frequency": 49.97493,
    "Voltage": 233.171,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 16.3174,
      "Active Power": 64.859,
      "Apparent Power": 66.8801
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-25-31pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.982661,
    "Energy": 452112,
    "Current": 0.366293,
    "Frequency": 50.00795,
    "Voltage": 228.9532,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 11.17299,
      "Active Power": 59.2152,
      "Apparent Power": 60.26007
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-59-52pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.980516,
    "Energy": 451726,
    "Current": 0.367371,
    "Frequency": 49.9338,
    "Voltage": 228.9015,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 11.87182,
      "Active Power": 59.25758,
      "Apparent Power": 60.43509
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-29-00pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 175233400000000.0,
    "Current": 0.68599,
    "Frequency": 49.9986,
    "Voltage": 234.4206,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 114.3018,
      "Apparent Power": 114.3018
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "8-05-31pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 453781,
    "Current": 0.775602,
    "Frequency": 50.10056,
    "Voltage": 232.3998,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 168.1695,
      "Apparent Power": 168.1695
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-40-34pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.971345,
    "Energy": 812655200000.0,
    "Current": 0.408437,
    "Frequency": 49.95142,
    "Voltage": 232.8839,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 16.23731,
      "Active Power": 66.3595,
      "Apparent Power": 68.31715
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-49-24pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.973081,
    "Energy": 450632,
    "Current": 0.406154,
    "Frequency": 50.02381,
    "Voltage": 233.1952,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 15.79622,
      "Active Power": 66.69606,
      "Apparent Power": 68.54112
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-37-43pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.973079,
    "Energy": 451387,
    "Current": 0.367561,
    "Frequency": 49.95623,
    "Voltage": 230.039,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 14.0511,
      "Active Power": 59.32494,
      "Apparent Power": 60.96624
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-22-07pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.967638,
    "Energy": 451150,
    "Current": 0.371291,
    "Frequency": 50.04655,
    "Voltage": 231.8856,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 15.92136,
      "Active Power": 61.05223,
      "Apparent Power": 63.09409
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-35-48pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.954589,
    "Energy": 450408,
    "Current": 0.406308,
    "Frequency": 49.94038,
    "Voltage": 234.548,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 20.55201,
      "Active Power": 65.85101,
      "Apparent Power": 68.98363
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-52-22pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.964322,
    "Energy": 52026600000.0,
    "Current": 0.400216,
    "Frequency": 49.98868,
    "Voltage": 233.5072,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 17.87965,
      "Active Power": 65.12939,
      "Apparent Power": 67.53902
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-04-32pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.984557,
    "Energy": 451787,
    "Current": 0.377961,
    "Frequency": 49.99628,
    "Voltage": 228.8851,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 10.86678,
      "Active Power": 61.11529,
      "Apparent Power": 62.07387
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-22-23pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.983272,
    "Energy": 452056,
    "Current": 0.368323,
    "Frequency": 49.95684,
    "Voltage": 228.6384,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 10.86979,
      "Active Power": 58.67836,
      "Apparent Power": 59.67665
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-46-14pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 1041043000000.0,
    "Current": 0.765907,
    "Frequency": 50.0134,
    "Voltage": 229.5993,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": -6.330518,
      "Active Power": 164.8743,
      "Apparent Power": 164.9958
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-25-44pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 450135,
    "Current": 0.701616,
    "Frequency": 49.9752,
    "Voltage": 233.7743,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 126.2498,
      "Apparent Power": 126.2498
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-26-40pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 450156,
    "Current": 0.690244,
    "Frequency": 49.97268,
    "Voltage": 233.7955,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 119.9844,
      "Apparent Power": 119.9844
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-27-20pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.965532,
    "Energy": 451221,
    "Current": 0.366259,
    "Frequency": 49.98304,
    "Voltage": 231.6522,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 15.70822,
      "Active Power": 58.27034,
      "Apparent Power": 60.35049
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-22-53pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.983747,
    "Energy": 452072,
    "Current": 0.369386,
    "Frequency": 49.92938,
    "Voltage": 228.722,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 10.84776,
      "Active Power": 59.43203,
      "Apparent Power": 60.41391
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-25-17pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 66831600000000.0,
    "Current": 0.71237,
    "Frequency": 49.9821,
    "Voltage": 232.9452,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 135.69,
      "Apparent Power": 135.69
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-41-05pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.961173,
    "Energy": 450495,
    "Current": 0.400472,
    "Frequency": 49.95229,
    "Voltage": 233.4269,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 18.36093,
      "Active Power": 63.95458,
      "Apparent Power": 66.53805
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "8-02-19pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 28357,
    "Current": 0.776914,
    "Frequency": 50.05984,
    "Voltage": 232.5406,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 0,
      "Active Power": 168.1897,
      "Apparent Power": 168.1897
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "6-35-32pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.970636,
    "Energy": 451344,
    "Current": 0.3705,
    "Frequency": 49.96972,
    "Voltage": 231.0655,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 14.79476,
      "Active Power": 59.69741,
      "Apparent Power": 61.50338
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-40-19pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.971345,
    "Energy": 812655200000.0,
    "Current": 0.408437,
    "Frequency": 49.95142,
    "Voltage": 232.8839,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 16.23731,
      "Active Power": 66.3595,
      "Apparent Power": 68.31715
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "11-17-59am": {
    "Power Factor": 0.998577,
    "Energy": 443861,
    "Current": 0.695875,
    "Frequency": 49.92556,
    "Voltage": 235.701,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 6.310611,
      "Active Power": 118.1622,
      "Apparent Power": 118.3306
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "7-29-16pm": {
    "Power Factor": 1,
    "Energy": 452261,
    "Current": 0.766003,
    "Frequency": 50.00531,
    "Voltage": 228.854,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": -6.902398,
      "Active Power": 164.5088,
      "Apparent Power": 164.6535
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  },
  "5-39-15pm": {
    "Power Factor": 0.966927,
    "Energy": 450469,
    "Current": 0.401578,
    "Frequency": 49.94552,
    "Voltage": 232.8963,
    "Powers": {
      "Reactive Power": 17.22237,
      "Active Power": 65.2914,
      "Apparent Power": 67.52464
    },
    "Price": 0,
    "THDs": {
      "Voltage THD": 400,
      "Current THD": 400
    }
  }
}
```

I want to convert it to csv/excel format and make it like this:
[CSV Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IUtB.png)

I have converted this from [this site](https://json-csv.com/). They have an API for conversion, but that code is giving an error in "urlparse" and also it has a limit that it can only convert a json data less than 1MB at a time.

I am stuck on this problem for some time now, if anybody can help.

Comment: Relevant question and links therein: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe. Convert to data frame first and then save to `.csv`.

Comment: @gented I have tried the codes on the link you provided, but none of them seems to give me the output like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/df7yW.png)

Comment: @Prateek that's because that isn't the header structure your JSON has. Apparently, you want to automagically flatten nested headers by concatenation when converting. How about some custom postprocessing of your dataframe? Some food for thought could come from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26458770/1864036) answer on the thread mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: Thanks @starturtle, had to write a custom script for my need as per your advice. A late reply, but still thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Excel for this process, you can use `Power Query`.

I stored the JSON document in a local file, and then

- `Data --> Get & Transform --> Get Data --> From File --> From JSON file`
- In the Power Query UI, I converted the resultant List of records to a Table

  - Then expand the column of Records
  - Then expand the few resultant Records column after expanding the table
- You can then save the file as a `CSV` file.

*If there were a large number of `Records` columns to be expanded, you could write a recursive routine, but with just a few, it's simpler to do it manually*

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\test.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value", {"Power Factor", "Energy", "Current", "Frequency", "Voltage", "Powers", "Price", "THDs"}, {"Power Factor", "Energy", "Current", "Frequency", "Voltage", "Powers", "Price", "THDs"}),
    #"Expanded THDs" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "THDs", {"Voltage THD", "Current THD"}, {"Voltage THD", "Current THD"}),
    #"Expanded Powers" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded THDs", "Powers", {"Reactive Power", "Active Power", "Apparent Power"}, {"Reactive Power", "Active Power", "Apparent Power"})
in
    #"Expanded Powers"
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: can you please share your code snippet. It'll be really helpful.

Comment: Ohh you wrote in MS-Excel. I want to do it with Python only.

Comment: @Prateek Unfortunately, I can't help you with that. But I'll leave this answer up in case someone else finds it useful.