# Join list by AND operator in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of boolean conditions with pandas/numpy. For example

```
cond1 = x > 5
cond2 = x > 6
cond3 = x > 8
...
list_conds = [cond1, cond2, cond3, ...]
```

I want to mix them to produce the condition

```
cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & ...
```

How can I get this?

Comment: `all(list_conds)`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `all()` function which will check that all the items in the iterable are true, so `all(list_conds)` for built-in python or numpy's `all()`  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html or pandas dataframe `all()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe