# Recursive addition/formating of JSONs in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am currently having a 1000 JSON's in the following format, each for a single employee:

```
        "A": "A_text",
        "B": "Datetime stamp of record",
        "ID": "123",
        "FeatureList": {
            "Salary": 100000,
            "Age": 45,
            "Work Ex": 15,
                       }
         }
```

My goal is to recursively concatenate these files into one df (see below):

[image]

In my current solution:
I can recursively add all files after formatting with:

```
rootdir ='/folderpath/filename'
all_files = Path(rootdir).rglob('*.json')
```

I am able to read the file and transpose it with below:

```
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df = df.transpose()
```

But the array buffer look-alike "FeatureList" is creating distorted orientation if I drop or create new columns.

[image]

Any advise on my approach would really help. Thanks

Comment: Could you share the distorted orientation output? :)

Comment: This link will help solve your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21266043/4285029

Comment: @Josh Laird, edited the question, adding the distorted view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your json, then you can use `json_normalize`:

```
with open('1.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data).drop(columns=['A']).rename(columns={'B': 'Date'})
print(df)

                       Date   ID  FeatureList.Salary  FeatureList.Age  FeatureList.Work Ex
0  Datetime stamp of record  123              100000               45                   15
```

Comment: Using Python 3.6, Getting AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: '0.25.3' @NYC Coder

Comment: You should upgrade to 1.0.5

Comment: I upgraded to 1.0.5. In place of data I am using the path to JSON. Still getting error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: data is a dict which is loaded from a file: check my updated answer

Comment: Any idea if it is possible to recursively open and read as I have 50 folders each with 1000 files. Currently for CSVs I use rootdir ='/folderpath/filename'
all_files = Path(rootdir).rglob('*.csv') . It takes a lot of SWAP memory when I am using good ol for loops.