# JSON file is pulled to Pandas DataFrame in one line. Can't break it down

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I am struggling with the conversion of JSON to DataFrame.
I get a JSON as a result of API request.

I tried pd.read_json, and pd.json_normalize and nothing helps.
The result is always a DataFrame with (1,1) shape.
I went through similar requests but looks like json_normalize helps everyone except me.

This is how my code looks today:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://******************************/parameters/100135?from=1h",
                        auth = ('*******', '*******'), verify=False)
t = response.text

stud_obj = json.loads(t)
m = pd.json_normalize(stud_obj)
```

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
 "DataList" : [
  {
   "Parameter" : 100135,
   "Parameter Label" : "TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level 3 (6); Duration Of Waterings {",
   "DataSet" : [
    {
     "Data" : "0:00:00",
     "Time" : "Fri Jun 25 00:00:01 2021"
    },
    {
     "Data" : "0:00:01",
     "Time" : "Fri Jun 25 07:51:33 2021"
    },
    {
     "Data" : "0:00:02",
     "Time" : "Fri Jun 25 07:51:34 2021"
    },
    {
     "Data" : "0:00:03",
     "Time" : "Fri Jun 25 07:51:35 2021"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Here is a DataFrame as a result:

```
print(m)
                                                DataList
    0  [{'Parameter': 100135, 'Parameter Label': 'TC3...
m.shape
    (1, 1)
```

Comment: How you would like to see your desired DataFrame? by two distinct columns like `data` and `Time`.

Comment: Try m = pd.DataFrame(stud_obj['Dataset'])

Comment: Please see if this [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe) helps.

Answer (score 2):

There may be efficient solution but untill you can use:

```
out=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(data).explode().tolist()).explode('DataSet',ignore_index=True)
#Here data is your json
```

Finally:

```
out=out.join(pd.DataFrame(out.pop('DataSet').tolist()))
```

output of out:

```
    Parameter   Parameter Label                                 Data     Time
0   100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level ...   0:00:00     Fri Jun 25 00:00:01 2021
1   100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level ...   0:00:01     Fri Jun 25 07:51:33 2021
2   100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level ...   0:00:02     Fri Jun 25 07:51:34 2021
3   100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level ...   0:00:03     Fri Jun 25 07:51:35 2021
```

Comment: @KarnKumar Thank you sir but it don't seem to be efficient

Comment: thats okay, Solution may vary but it should be working before we go to efficiency :-) i think the link i provide that will be good to follow.

Comment: Oh! It replaced all values with the first one. That's bad. Anurag-Dabas , do you know how to solve this? Sorry, I badly understand on what step of a code it happens.

Comment: @OlegKazanskyi  Fixed it...Kindly have a look ***:)***

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) + [`pd.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), as follows:

Using your loaded json `stud_obj`:

```
df_out = pd.json_normalize(stud_obj['DataList']).explode('DataSet').reset_index(drop=True)

df_out = pd.concat([df_out.drop('DataSet', axis=1), pd.DataFrame(df_out['DataSet'].to_list())], axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


   Parameter                                                               Parameter Label     Data                      Time
0     100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level 3 (6); Duration Of Waterings {  0:00:00  Fri Jun 25 00:00:01 2021
1     100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level 3 (6); Duration Of Waterings {  0:00:01  Fri Jun 25 07:51:33 2021
2     100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level 3 (6); Duration Of Waterings {  0:00:02  Fri Jun 25 07:51:34 2021
3     100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level 3 (6); Duration Of Waterings {  0:00:03  Fri Jun 25 07:51:35 2021
```

Comment: Thanks @SeaBean for noticing ***:)***

Comment: @OlegKazanskyi Pleased to help!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

`pd.json_normalize()` can do the job by itself:

```
d = { ... your JSON object ... }
pd.json_normalize(d,['DataList','DataSet'],[['DataList','Parameter'],['DataList','Parameter Label']])

     Data             Time            DataList.Parameter     DataList.Parameter Label
0   0:00:00     Fri Jun 25 00:00:01 2021    100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level ...
1   0:00:01     Fri Jun 25 07:51:33 2021    100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level ...
2   0:00:02     Fri Jun 25 07:51:34 2021    100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level ...
3   0:00:03     Fri Jun 25 07:51:35 2021    100135  TC3; GR53; Irrigation Zones GR53; Row 2 Level ...
```