# Converting JSON file to Pandas data

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, operating-system

I have not worked with JSON files so far, I have to resolve a requirement of filtering some data from a huge JSON file with lots of  information
Q1. should I change this JSON file into Pandas data frame and filter the desired information
will it not be a bad coding technique
Q2 how to filter data directly from JSON file in python

first few lines of JSON file actually the file is 30 times more of code and can not be posted here
but filtering this very code will give me intuition to withdraw and store information

```
      {
      "response":{
    "status_code":200,
    "data":{
        "id":18288,
        "code":"u2vx",
        "accepts_instructions":true,
        "address":"76 Z block commercial market Phase-3 DHA Lahore.",
        "address_line2":"76 Z block commercial market Phase-3 DHA Lahore.",
        "budget":3,
        "chain":{
            "id":2,
            "is_accepting_global_vouchers":true,
            "main_vendor_code":"s0ox",
            "main_vendor_id":1439,
            "name":"KFC",
            "url_key":"kfc",
            "code":"cs5rw"
        },
        "city":{
            "id":200253,
            "name":"Lahore",
            "url_key":"lahore",
            "is_top_city":false,
            "is_main_city":false,
            "is_express_delivery_enabled":false,
            "latitude":31.510849,
            "longitude":74.37538147,
            "timezone":"Asia/Karachi"
        },
        "cuisines":[
            {
                "id":86,
                "name":"Fast Food",
                "url_key":"fast-food",
                "main":true
            }
        ],
        "custom_location_url":"",
        "customer_phone":"+3202440571, 0423-5746464, 0423-5692414, Mr Babar\t0301-4147257, 
           0332-1494447, 0332-1494448",
        "customer_type":"all",
        "delivery_box":"",
        "delivery_conditions":[
            {
                "delivery_fee":0,
                "delivery_fee_type":"amount",
                "minimum_order_amount":0,
                "maximum_order_amount":0
            }
        ],
        "delivery_fee_type":"amount",
        "delivery_fee_source":"disco",
        "delivery_provider_id":0,
        "description":"",
        "discounts":[
            
        ],
        "distance":8533.565,
        "experiments":[
            {
                "experiment_id":"recommendation-products-elements",
                "experiment_variation":"Control",
                "is_participating":false
            },
            {
                "experiment_id":"vendor-details-availability-concurrent",
                "experiment_variation":"Control",
                "is_participating":false
            },
            {
                "experiment_id":"recommendation-products-quantity",
                "experiment_variation":"Control",
                "is_participating":false
            }
        ],
        "food_characteristics":[
            {
                "id":120,
                "name":"Halal",
                "is_halal":true,
                "is_vegetarian":false
            },
            {
                "id":129,
                "name":"foodpanda delivery",
                "is_halal":true,
                "is_vegetarian":false
            }
        ],
        "favorite_data":null,
        "has_delivery_provider":true,
        "hero_image":"https://images.deliveryhero.io/image/fd-pk/LH/u2vx-hero.jpg",
        "hero_listing_image":"https://images.deliveryhero.io/image/fd-pk/LH/u2vx-listing.jpg",
        "is_active":true,
        "is_busy":false,
        "is_best_in_city":false,
        "is_checkout_comment_enabled":true,
        "is_delivery_enabled":true,
        "is_express_delivery_available":false,
        "is_express_delivery_enabled":false,
        "is_new":false,
        "is_new_until":"2019-09-07T00:00:00Z",
        "is_pickup_enabled":false,
        "is_premium":false,
        "premium_position":0,
        "is_preorder_enabled":false,
        "is_promoted":false,
        "is_replacement_dish_enabled":false,
        "is_service_fee_enabled":false,
        "is_service_tax_enabled":false,
        "is_service_tax_visible":false,
        "is_test":false,
        "is_vat_disabled":false,
        "is_vat_included_in_product_price":true,
        "is_vat_visible":false,
        "is_vat_included":true,
        "is_voucher_enabled":false,
        "latitude":31.473286,
        "location_event":null,
        "logo":"",
        "longitude":74.378387,
        "loyalty_percentage_amount":0,
        "loyalty_program_enabled":false,
        "maximum_express_order_amount":0,
        "menus":[
            {
                "id":35895,
                "code":"",
                "name":"Mid Night Menu",
                "description":"",
                "type":"delivery",
                "opening_time":"00:01:00",
                "closing_time":"06:00:00",
                "menu_categories":[
                    {
                        "id":284921,
                        "code":"s6ey-mc-5gy",
                        "name":"Midnight Deals",
                        "description":"(Starting From 12:00am)",
                        "products":[
                            {
                                "id":2148024,
                                "code":"s6ey-pr-owmq",
                                "name":"Midnight Deal 1",
                                "description":"Zinger burger with regular soft drink",
                                "display_price":"",
                                "master_category_id":8,
                                "file_path":"https://images.deliveryhero.io/image/fd- 
                                   pk/Products/1164992.png?width=%s",
                                "logo_path":"https://images.deliveryhero.io/image/fd- 
                               pk/Products/1164992.png?width=%s",
                                "images_urls":[
                                    
                                ],
                                "images":[
                                    {
                                        "image_url":"https://images.deliveryhero.io/image/fd- 
                            pk/Products/1164992.png",
                                        "tags":{
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "is_prepacked_item":false,
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: response
data         {'id': 18288, 'code': 'u2vx', 'accepts_instruc...
status_code                                                200

Comment: No, the solution is not up to the mark, the output is neither readable nor editable no segregation of keys and values

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(r'directory\Name.json')
df.head()
```

Comment: response
data         {'id': 18288, 'code': 'u2vx', 'accepts_instruc...
status_code                                                200 //is all that i get as output  can not do any operations , need to drop some columns

Answer (score 0):

If your data is unstructured, you have to open your file using `json`, like this:

[JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Otherwise, if it is already in a tabular structure, use Nikunj's answer, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(r'directory\Name.json')
df.head()
```