# how to convert one column of dataframe into distributive column which has values in json format (PYTHON)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-science

lets say i have a dataframe value

e.g. test_data.csv (contain below data)

```
effective_date,ds,id,id_type,e_data,create_id,create_timestamp
2021-07-26,am,27,a_id,"{""cup_id"": ""ffdsds"", ""rate"": ""B"", ""direct"": ""stable"", ""dl_tstmp"": ""2021-07-26 00:00:00"", ""inst_id"": 1213, ""src_p_tstmp"": ""2021-07-26 00:00:00"", ""inst_name"": ""abc corp""}",MA,2021-07-26 00:00:00
2021-07-26,am,24,a_id,"{""cup_id"": ""ererwe"", ""rate"": ""AB"", ""direct"": ""improvent"", ""dl_tstmp"": ""2021-07-26 00:00:00"", ""inst_id"": 66641, ""src_p_tstmp"": ""2021-07-26 00:00:00"", ""inst_name"": ""xyz corp""}",MA,2021-07-26 00:00:00
2021-07-27,am,22,a_id,"{""cup_id"": ""34kf3"", ""rate"": ""AA"", ""direct"": ""improvent"", ""dl_tstmp"": ""2021-07-26 00:00:00"", ""inst_id"": 6871, ""src_p_tstmp"": ""2021-07-26 00:00:00"", ""inst_name"": ""rimr corp""}",MA,2021-07-26 00:00:00
2021-07-27,am,32,a_id,"{""cup_id"": ""5gh23"", ""rate"": ""AAA"", ""direct"": ""downfall"", ""dl_tstmp"": ""2021-07-26 00:00:00"", ""inst_id"": 98795, ""src_p_tstmp"": ""2021-07-26 00:00:00"", ""inst_name"": ""prst corp""}",MA,2021-07-26 00:00:00


import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
```

[image]

in which **e_data** column is in **json_format** **not in dictionary** format
[image]

which i wanted to **distribute** into separate **column** format
hence the expected output is as follows

[image]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so the answer can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly convert the string dict to real dict:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['e_data']=df['e_data'].map(literal_eval)
```

Finally:

try `join()`+`DataFrame()`+`tolist()` and `pop()` for removing 'e_data' column:

```
df=df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('e_data').tolist()))
```

OR

```
df=df.join(df['e_data'].apply(pd.Series)).drop('e_data',1)
```

Comment: hi @anurag dabas  actually this logic is working fine here but while i am running it in my data set it is not working because it may fine over dictionary but not in json the column i am having store value in json format not in dictionary

Comment: @AnilTiwari so post that format in the question instead of posting a Series of dictionaries

Comment: @AnilTiwari so how you are reading it?..I mean you can tell the seprator?

Comment: basically it is csv

Comment: @AnilTiwari yes sir I know that's why I asking the seperator that you are using in `read_csv()` method to load the csv file

Comment: i have change the data which will more helpful now you can simply read it by df = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")

Comment: @AnilTiwari updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**