# Converting to dataframe, beginner question

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a piece of data that looks like this

```
    my_data[:5]
```

returns:

```
    [{'key': ['Aaliyah', '2', '2016'], 'values': ['10']},
     {'key': ['Aaliyah', '2', '2017'], 'values': ['26']},
     {'key': ['Aaliyah', '2', '2018'], 'values': ['21']},
     {'key': ['Aaliyah', '2', '2019'], 'values': ['26']},
     {'key': ['Aaliyah', '2', '2020'], 'values': ['15']}]
```

The key represents Name, Gender, and Year. The value is number.
I do not manage to generate a data frame with columns name, gender, year, and number.

Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using a generator:

```
from itertools import chain
pd.DataFrame.from_records((dict(zip(['name', 'gender', 'year', 'number'],
                                    chain(*e.values())))
                           for e in my_data))
```

Without itertools:

```
pd.DataFrame(((E:=list(e.values()))[0]+E[1] for e in my_data),
             columns=['name', 'gender', 'year', 'number'])
```

output:

```
      name gender  year number
0  Aaliyah      2  2016     10
1  Aaliyah      2  2017     26
2  Aaliyah      2  2018     21
3  Aaliyah      2  2019     26
4  Aaliyah      2  2020     15
```