# Python JSON GET Request to File

Tags: python

I'm new to Python but I have an GET Request using requests which is showing me what I want to see, however, how am I able to export it out to a column in CSV?

```
import requests
url = '<URL>'
response = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth = ('username', 'pass'))
jsonResponse = response.json()
print("NAME")
print(jsonResponse["limits"]['assets'])
```

The response is:
NAME
Number (As Assets is nested)

Ideally I'd like to show both NAME and Number in different columns:
NAME | Number

My plan is to have multiple requests in the one script which will then spit out a CSV file with the data I'm trying to capture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSV module

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', mode='a') as file:
    w = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(['NAME', jsonResponse["limits"]['assets']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm using an atomic bomb to kill a fly, but I would consider to build the whole data structure into a pandas dataframe and then export it. [Check here to transform json to df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe) and [here to export to csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Yes, that's a lengthy & unnecessary step

Comment: You missed the point. OP does 1 request per row and only uses 1 single value per json, so there is no Json to convert to csv.

Comment: hummm... if is just aggregate several JSON requests into a CSV, I'd go with the CSV module...