# Convert json dict and list

Tags: python, json, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have pulled JSON data from a URL. The result is a dictionary. How can I transform this dictionary to a dataframe so AdrActCnt and AdrBal1in100KCnt are columns, and the time is the index for each value.

Thanks in advance

```
{"data":[
{"asset":"btc","time":"2009-01-04T00:00:00.00000000Z","AdrActCnt":"10","AdrBal1in100KCnt":"145"},
{"asset":"btc","time":"2009-01-05T00:00:00.00000000Z","AdrActCnt":"30","AdrBal1in100KCnt":"152"},
{"asset":"btc","time":"2009-01-06T00:00:00.00000000Z","AdrActCnt":"50","AdrBal1in100KCnt":"136"}
]}

time----------------------------------------AdrActCnt---------AdrBal1in100KCnt
    
2009-01-04T00:00:00.00000000Z------------------10-------------------145
2009-01-05T00:00:00.00000000Z------------------30-------------------152
2009-01-06T00:00:00.00000000Z------------------50-------------------136
```

Comment: are you looking to convert [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21104592/10197418)?

Comment: Do you just want to print the data in a formatted way?

Comment: yes, I want to see this data in a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

I would make sure that I am using one of the latest python versions, because of sort in dictionaries or data source structure can be changed, better I will add sorting for dictionary and list for this code.

```py
import pandas as pd

obj = {"data":[
{"asset":"btc","time":"2009-01-04T00:00:00.00000000Z","AdrActCnt":"10","AdrBal1in100KCnt":"145"},
{"asset":"btc","time":"2009-01-05T00:00:00.00000000Z","AdrActCnt":"30","AdrBal1in100KCnt":"152"},
{"asset":"btc","time":"2009-01-06T00:00:00.00000000Z","AdrActCnt":"50","AdrBal1in100KCnt":"136"}
]}


def value(obj, keys):
    for dicit in obj["data"]:
        values = [
            value
            for key, value in dicit.items()
            if key in keys
        ]
        yield values

keys = ["time", "AdrActCnt", "AdrBal1in100KCnt"]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[x for x in value(obj, keys)]
    , columns=keys
)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                            time AdrActCnt AdrBal1in100KCnt
0  2009-01-04T00:00:00.00000000Z        10              145
1  2009-01-05T00:00:00.00000000Z        30              152
2  2009-01-06T00:00:00.00000000Z        50              136
```

If dictionaries can be randomly sorted (not ordered) or I want to make sure that it is sorted, so I would try an example below:

```py
### Another sort

keys = ["AdrBal1in100KCnt", "AdrActCnt", "time"]

def value(obj, keys):
    for dictis in obj["data"]:
        listed = [dictis[x] for x in keys]
        yield listed

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[x for x in value(obj, keys)]
    , columns=keys
)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  AdrBal1in100KCnt AdrActCnt                           time
0              145        10  2009-01-04T00:00:00.00000000Z
1              152        30  2009-01-05T00:00:00.00000000Z
2              136        50  2009-01-06T00:00:00.00000000Z
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!!

Comment: addited, using indexes for sort.