# Convert json data into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, api

I am unable to flatten the json data from this API into a dataframe. I have tried using json_normalize but I gives a NotImplemented error. Can someone help me with it? I need the columns: *stationId, start, timestep, temperature* where there are several values for temperature and rest of the columns should have same values.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

response_API = requests.get('https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10865,G005')
print(response_API.status_code)
data = response_API.text
json.loads(data)

df= ?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: use `response_API.json()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it many ways, but your current approach should use `json()` instead of `text`

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

response_API = requests.get('https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10865,G005')
print(response_API.status_code)
data = response_API.json()        <--- it should be json()
print(data)
```

**OR** directly read `json` to `df` from the URL using `read_json()`

```
df = pd.read_json("https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10865,G005")
print(df)
```

**Edit:**

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

response_API = requests.get('https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=10865,G005')
print(response_API.status_code)
data = response_API.json()

result = []
for station, value in data.items():
    for forecast, val in value.items():
        if forecast in ['forecast1', 'forecast2']:
            result.append(val)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have editted my question. I am unable to convert json data into a desired format. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Check my edit @ChhandoseeBhattacharya