# how to represent rows and columns in database from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Team,
I have a python nested dict object that I created after iterating over several files.
I then converted it to json str with `json_dumps` then i passed it to pandas creating dataframe. Now, I uploaded it to database but my database is missing the rows.

python nested dictionary
nested_dict

```
 {'av1':{'parent_child1': {'cpu': 3, 'server': 2, 'mixer': 3}, 'parent_child2': {'server': 9, 'mixer': 1, 'cpu': 5}, 'parent_child3': {'mixer': 4, 'server': 4, 'cpu': 6}, 'parent_child4': {'cpu': 2, 'mixer': 1, 'server': 3}, 'parent_child5': {'cpu': 224, 'server': 620, 'mixer': 131}}}}
```

json_dumps of nested_dict[av1])

```
 {"parent_child1": {"cpu": 3, "server": 2, "mixer": 3}, "parent_child2": {"server": 9, "mixer": 1, "cpu": 5}, "parent_child3": {"mixer": 4, "server": 4, "cpu": 6}, "parent_child4": {"cpu": 2, "mixer": 1, "server": 3}, "parent_child5": {"cpu": 224, "server": 620, "mixer": 131}}}
```

manual representation is

```
{
  “av1”: {
    “parent_child1”: {
      "cpu": 3,
      "server": 2,
      "mixer": 3
    },
    "parent_child2”: {
      "server": 9,
      "mixer": 1,
      "cpu": 5
    },
    "parent_child3”: {
      "mixer": 4,
      "server": 4,
      "cpu": 6
    },
    "parent_child4”: {
      "cpu": 2,
      "mixer": 1,
      "server": 3
    },
    "parent_child5”: {
      "cpu": 224,
      "server": 620,
      "mixer": 131
    }
  }
}
```

```
 df1 = pd.read_json.format_dict())
 df2=(df1['av1'].apply(pd.Series))
```

before pushing to Database below is dataframe which i converted with pandas

`print(df1)`

```
               parent_child1  parent_child2  parent_child3  parent_child4  parent_child5
server                   3              5              6              2              224
cpu                  2              9              4              3              620
mixer                3              1              4              1              131
```

So I need help push the dataframe as is such that I retain the servers too server,mixer,cpu
but below shows am loosing the server,mixer,cpu and it is replaced by 0,1,2.

above parent_child1 is a column and server is row. but below I lost all servers. any hint how can i push them to table and then I should be able to run query like

`select parent1_child1 from tble_db where row=server`

`print(df2)`
output

```
      parent_child1  parent_child2  parent_child3  parent_child4  parent_child5
0           3         5          6         2       224
1           2         9          4         3       620
2           3         1          4         1       131
```

Comment: I would skip the pandas conversion and parse the json into a database structure. You need to make a call how much you want to normalise your data structure in mysql. Will you create 1 table with a json column for children or will you create two tables and relate parent and child entries or will you create just a children table that has parent as a column as parent does not seem to have additional properties.

Comment: very good probe. yeah: just a children table that has parent as a column as parent does not seem to have additional properties

Comment: OK, so where are you stuck with this? You seem to need two loops to generate the insert statements.

Comment: am stuck at `print(df2)` if you see my rows are lost. `server,mixer,cpu` each child has unique has unique of those values.

Comment: Do not use pandas. Work with your json file. Or you need to change how you convert your json to pandas, but then your question has nothing to do with mysql.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe