# inserting the all the responses of an api output to pandas dataframe with indivdual column names

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a json response as below.

```
['{"accountNumber":"2130005","billDayModelName":"","billDayModelScore":"0","defaultBadWriteOffModelName":"XYZ","defaultBadWriteOffModelScore":600.677286,"accountModelName":"","accountModelScore":"0","customerModelName":"","customerModelScore":"0","accountRiskCode":"","customerRiskCode":""}', '{"ACCTNBR":"2130005","PREV3MOTOTAMT":0,"PREV3CALL":1,"DAY_SYNC":4,"STD_DVTN":79.72,"MNTHCNT":2,"AVG_AMT":0,"PMT_CNT":0}', '[{"ACCT_NBR":2130005,"ACCOUNT_SCORE":0.8,"BHVR_SCR":380}]']
```

would like to all the values to a pandas dataframe with individual column names with values as coming in the response.

Is there any way to pass all the columns with values in a single dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No, Its does not provide the answer of my question. If you notice i have another list inside the list and the columns have be present in one row. As of now i have provided only one sample record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a list in your json response, you need to flatten it:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

json_response = [
    '{"accountNumber":"2130005","billDayModelName":"","billDayModelScore":"0","defaultBadWriteOffModelName":"XYZ","defaultBadWriteOffModelScore":600.677286,"accountModelName":"","accountModelScore":"0","customerModelName":"","customerModelScore":"0","accountRiskCode":"","customerRiskCode":""}',
    '{"ACCTNBR":"2130005","PREV3MOTOTAMT":0,"PREV3CALL":1,"DAY_SYNC":4,"STD_DVTN":79.72,"MNTHCNT":2,"AVG_AMT":0,"PMT_CNT":0}',
    '[{"ACCT_NBR":2130005,"ACCOUNT_SCORE":0.8,"BHVR_SCR":380}]'
]

def normalize_key(d):
    key_mapping = {
        'ACCTNBR': 'accountNumber',
        'ACCT_NBR': 'accountNumber'
    }
    return {key_mapping.get(k, k): v for k, v in d.items()}

dicts = [json.loads(item) for item in json_response if item.startswith('{')]
list_of_dicts = [json.loads(item) for item in json_response if item.startswith('[')]

for item in list_of_dicts:
    dicts.extend(item)

normalized_dicts = [normalize_key(d) for d in dicts]

merged_dict = {}
for d in normalized_dicts:
    merged_dict.update(d)

df = pd.DataFrame([merged_dict])

print(df)
```

which is

```
   accountNumber billDayModelName billDayModelScore  \
0        2130005                                  0   

  defaultBadWriteOffModelName  defaultBadWriteOffModelScore accountModelName  \
0                         XYZ                    600.677286                    

  accountModelScore customerModelName customerModelScore accountRiskCode  \
0                 0                                    0                   

  customerRiskCode  PREV3MOTOTAMT  PREV3CALL  DAY_SYNC  STD_DVTN  MNTHCNT  \
0                               0          1         4     79.72        2   

   AVG_AMT  PMT_CNT  ACCOUNT_SCORE  BHVR_SCR  
0        0        0            0.8       380
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it should in one row instead of three rows.The response I have shared is for only on json output. So it should create only one record in dataframe.

Comment: @Debasis i updated my answer return a single row