# Create Python DataFrame from dictionary where keys are the column names and values form the row

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I am familiar with python but new to panda DataFrames. I have a dictionary like this:

```
a={'b':100,'c':300}
```

And I would like to convert it to a DataFrame, where b and c are the column names, and the first row is 100,300 (100 is underneath b and 300 is underneath c). I would like a solution that can be generalized to a much longer dictionary, with many more items. Thank you!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-dataframe/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Pass the values as a list:

```
a={'b':[100,],'c':[300,]}
pd.DataFrame(a)

     b    c
0  100  300
```

Or if for some reason you don't want to use a list, include an index:

```
a={'b':100,'c':300}
pd.DataFrame(a, index=['i',])

     b    c
i  100  300
```

Comment: I have several pd.np.nan values inserted in a list of dicts.. so each element of the list is either a dict. or a nan. How would I convert it into a dataframe?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  I think the approach here should work, but if not you should post this as a separate question so you can include example data

Comment: I figured it out, i changed it: now Appending a NaN filled dict i.e listt.append({"key" : pd.np.nan ....}) .. to the list.. rather than appending a pd.np.nan object directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use lists as the values in the dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'b':[100,200],'c':[300,400]}
b = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [4]: b
Out[4]: 
     b    c
0  100  300
1  200  400
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
loan_sanction_details = pd.DataFrame(event,index=['i',])
```

where `loan_sanction_details` is dataframe and `event` is dictionary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).