# Pandas data frame from dictionary returns values as tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples

Hey guys If someone could give me an explanation I would be very grateful.
This is a code:

```
#Dict- 
hours_year={'2018': 900 , '2019':456} 
# Making a df

df=pd.DataFrame({'Year': hours_year.keys(), 'Hours': hours_year.values()}) 
df
```

```
#Output

            Year    Hours
0   (2018, 2019)    (900, 456)

1   (2018, 2019)    (900, 456)
```

My question is- Why tuple? On other pc, same in jupyter it return normal df.
Could it be something with version of python that i'am using?? Just guessing..
Thanks for any help

Comment: That may depend on what version of pandas you used. in ver '1.2.0', It returns ` Year Hours
0 2018 900
1 2019 456`

Comment: That was my thought, so I updated pandas module and my currently version is 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318639/create-python-dataframe-from-dictionary-where-keys-are-the-column-names-and-valu):

```
pd.DataFrame(hours_year, index=['i',])
```

Else, you should try [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) function, but your data need to be list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hours_year, columns=['Years', 'Hours'])
```

Another solution but you need to change your data again :

```
hours_year={'2018': [900,] , '2019':[456,]}
pd.DataFrame(hours_year)
```

Comment: With that code a got: ValueError: cannot use columns parameter with orient='columns', so I add orient, df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hours_year,orient='index',columns=['Years', 'Hours']), then I got this ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (2, 2).
I solved the problem whit this code 
 details = { 
    'Year' :['2018','2019'], 
    'Hours' : [3702, 9818] 
} 
  
# creating a Dataframe object  
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
I just do not understand why it won't work with something that I used soo many times.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it
df=pd.DataFrame({'Year': list(hours_year.keys()), 'Hours': list(hours_year.values())})
Just putting a list IN front of value. And the original code works.
Still not sure why on one pc must stand list and on another not.