# converting a list of dictionaries to a data frame

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I referred to this link
[Convert list of dictionaries to Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-dataframe)
 but i get error of "**DataFrame constructor not properly called**"

I tried DataFrame.from_dict but the error is same.
The dictionary is the result from a database query. fetched from cursor.fetchall().

Thanks for help.

```
code: 
import MySQLdb
import pandas as pd
def query_run(sql):
    db=MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","user","password","db")
    cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchallDict()
        db.close()
    return data
query = "select * from table"
data = query_run(query)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data) #tried this as well as
dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) #this as well
```

i have some processing to do on dict data that's why i'm not fetching the rows as dataframes from database

Comment: Can you give example of your dict and a code u use to make the dataframe.

Comment: problem got solved from DataFrames.from_records(data)

Answer (score 2):

the problem got solved from using 
DataFrame.from_records(data)