# Why does concatenation of DataFrames get exponentially slower?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, concatenation, processing-efficiency

I have a function which processes a DataFrame, largely to process data into buckets create a binary matrix of features in a particular column using `pd.get_dummies(df[col])`.

To avoid processing all of my data using this function at once (which goes out of memory and causes iPython to crash), I have broken the large DataFrame into chunks using:

```
chunks = (len(df) / 10000) + 1
df_list = np.array_split(df, chunks)
```

`pd.get_dummies(df)` will automatically create new columns based on the contents of `df[col]` and these are likely to differ for each `df` in `df_list`.

After processing, I am concatenating the DataFrames back together using:

```
for i, df_chunk in enumerate(df_list):
    print "chunk", i
    [x, y] = preprocess_data(df_chunk)
    super_x = pd.concat([super_x, x], axis=0)
    super_y = pd.concat([super_y, y], axis=0)
    print datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

The processing time of the first chunk is perfectly acceptable, however, it grows per chunk! This is not to do with the `preprocess_data(df_chunk)` as there is no reason for it to increase. Is this increase in time occurring as a result of the call to `pd.concat()`?

Please see log below:

```
chunks 6
chunk 0
2016-04-08 00:22:17.728849
chunk 1
2016-04-08 00:22:42.387693 
chunk 2
2016-04-08 00:23:43.124381
chunk 3
2016-04-08 00:25:30.249369
chunk 4
2016-04-08 00:28:11.922305
chunk 5
2016-04-08 00:32:00.357365
```

Is there a workaround to speed this up? I have 2900 chunks to process so any help is appreciated!

Open to any other suggestions in Python!

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Never call `DataFrame.append` or `pd.concat` inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.

`pd.concat` returns a new DataFrame. Space has to be allocated for the new
DataFrame, and data from the old DataFrames have to be copied into the new
DataFrame. Consider the amount of copying required by this line inside the `for-loop` (assuming each `x` has size 1):

```
super_x = pd.concat([super_x, x], axis=0)

| iteration | size of old super_x | size of x | copying required |
|         0 |                   0 |         1 |                1 |
|         1 |                   1 |         1 |                2 |
|         2 |                   2 |         1 |                3 |
|       ... |                     |           |                  |
|       N-1 |                 N-1 |         1 |                N |
```

`1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N = N(N+1)/2`. So there is `O(N**2)` copies required to
complete the loop.

Now consider

```
super_x = []
for i, df_chunk in enumerate(df_list):
    [x, y] = preprocess_data(df_chunk)
    super_x.append(x)
super_x = pd.concat(super_x, axis=0)
```

[Appending to a list is an `O(1)` operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) and does not require copying.  Now
there is a single call to `pd.concat` after the loop is done. This call to
`pd.concat` requires N copies to be made, since `super_x` contains `N`
DataFrames of size 1. So when constructed this way, `super_x` requires `O(N)`
copies.

Comment: Hi @unutbu, thanks for the detailed explanation, this really explained the theory in detail!

Comment: Is it feasible to concatenate 2900 blocks of this shape, this way (43717, 3261)? The processing step now only takes 10 seconds.

Comment: if using concat in a loop, wouldn't deleting the old dataframes in the loop resolve the issue?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7: The issue is about speed, not memory. The peak memory usage is about the same either way. Copying can be a slow operation when the dataframe is large and/or the loop is performed many times. Making O(n^2) copies is unnecessarily slow, since there is an O(n) alternative -- append to a list, concat once after the loop.

Comment: Minor comment: 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N = N(N-1)/2 should it not be 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N = N(N+1)/2 ?

Comment: I think *copying* isn't the issue here, or `copy=False` should help. Every `concat` does quite some postprocessing, even though `verify_integrity=False` and `sort=False`. This takes longer as data grows and could be done at once at the end like this answer shows!

Comment: Applying your solution to my program with more than 1.5 M data records resulted in execution time going from 60+ hours to under 1h! And I even understand why...! :-)  Thanks!

Comment: Applying this to a Kaggle notebook crunching 1.4m very wide records reduced the execution time from something over 9 hours (timeout) to 25 minutes - thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation. Similarly, if there are multiple columns in the final dataset, then we can create a dictionary first, and then convert it to a data frame finally.

Answer (score 14):

Every time you concatenate, you are returning a copy of the data.

You want to keep a list of your chunks, and then concatenate everything as the final step.

```
df_x = []
df_y = []
for i, df_chunk in enumerate(df_list):
    print "chunk", i
    [x, y] = preprocess_data(df_chunk)
    df_x.append(x)
    df_y.append(y)

super_x = pd.concat(df_x, axis=0)
del df_x  # Free-up memory.
super_y = pd.concat(df_y, axis=0)
del df_y  # Free-up memory.
```

Comment: Trying to manage memory manually in such high-level languages like Python is a bad practice because actually you cannot manage memory like in C for example. What happens when you `del` a variable is that you [remove a binding] (https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) (third paragraph). Later garbage collector _may_ release memory, but when and what amount depends on the GC algorithm (which is quite complex).

Comment: @jbmeerkat I would only delete if the data had a large memory footprint or available memory was limited.  Also, it is easier to reassign, e.g. `df_x = pd.concat(df_x, axis=0)`.