# Struggling with choosing a variable type for data filtering in a for loop for probability study

Tags: python, pandas, variables, for-loop, output

I am trying to study the probability of having a zero value in my data and I have developed a code that outputs the value of a column of data when the other is zero which is what I need. But having to do that for each column vs all other 28 of my 577by29 dataframe is difficult so I decided to create a for loop that does that for me where I have this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
allchan = pd.read_csv('allchan.csv',delimiter = ' ')
allchanarray = np.array(allchan)
dfallchan = pd.DataFrame(allchanarray,range(1,578),dtype=float)
for n in range(0,29):
    print((dfallchan[(dfallchan[0]>0) & (dfallchan[n]==0)][0]))
    print((dfallchan[(dfallchan[0]>0) & (dfallchan[n]==0)][0].count()))
```

what I want to do is to assign each thing inside a print statement in a column of a variable of some kind (array, list, DataFrame, or series ) which I seem to be struggling with. and then save the output as an Excel file using `something.to_excel`, before I change the column that I am comparing to and so on. note that the output of the code should return different values of the first channel (column of input data) as the zeros are randomly distributed in my input file and each output column is expected to have a different length.
please help me with the code and explain to me why did you use one type of variable not the other

Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain with an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have 29 columns of data each contains 577 rows that have zero values randomly distributed through them. what I am trying to do is first compare the first column with the second one and print the values of the first column where the second is zero. for example: column one has (3,7,8,9,6) and column two has (4,0,6,7,0) I want to print the values (7,6) of the first column and then repeat for all other 28 columns of data while counting the number of first column's values which is in this example is 2 and save all that in an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

So you use the following feature of the `pandas`.

```
data = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
df

     0    1    2
0  1.0  4.0  1.0
1  2.0  5.0  2.0
2  3.0  NaN  3.0
3  NaN  NaN  4.0
4  NaN  NaN  5.0
5  NaN  NaN  6.0
6  NaN  NaN  7.0
```

The variable `data` is a list of lists. In your case you can have a list of your filtered values of 1st column. Function `transpose` flips the dimensions.

Accordingly, you can make further changes to add the number of values filtered from the 1st column.

Comment: Ok, I tried doing this: 


`x = pd.DataFrame()
for n in range(0,29):
    x[n] = dfallchan[(dfallchan[0]>0) & (dfallchan[n]==0)][0]
x`

but for some reason, my for loop spits invalid data for n>6

Comment: please take a look at my other question which has more explanation Here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573571/for-loop-to-create-a-matrix-in-python