# How can I export status of list of websites as 'Yes' or 'No' to csv from python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've imported a list of websites from csv file. I then checked every website to see if this is developed in wordpress or not. Now, I wanted to export wordpress status of every websited as 'Yes' or 'No' into a csv. 
From this code I could get status as either all 'Yes' or all 'No'. It returns the wordpress status of last runned website as the wordpress status of all websites. E.g: If wordpress status of last runned website is 'Yes' then status of all websites in csv is 'Yes'.

```
`wpLoginCheck = requests.get(websiteToScan + '/wp-login.php', headers=user_agent)
        print(f"wpLoginCheck: {wpLoginCheck}")
        if wpLoginCheck.status_code == 200:
            df['Status'] = 'Yes'
            df.to_csv('updated.csv', index=False)
        else:
            print ("Not detected")
            df['Status'] = 'No'
            df.to_csv('updated.csv', index=False)`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Status'] = 'Yes'
```

sets the variable 'Status' equal to Yes for all rows. If you want to change the value of a specific cell you need to use

```
df.at[i, 'Status'] = 'Yes'
```

Where i is the row index. 
If you want to add rows as the loop goes on, you can save the results in dictionaries and convert it to a dataframe in the end. See for example [How to append rows in a pandas dataframe in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674557/how-to-append-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be using apply function of a pandas Dataframe. Given that the website to scan is one of the columns, you could do:

```
def wpLoginCheck(row):
    requests.get(row['websiteToScan'] + '/wp-login.php', headers=user_agent)
    if wpLoginCheck.status_code == 200:
        return 'Yes'
    else:
        return'No'

df['Status'] = df.apply(wpLoginCheck, axis=1)
df.to_csv('updated.csv', index=False)
```