# Convert list of Dictionaries to a Dataframe

Tags: python, json, list, pandas, dictionary

I am facing a basic problem of converting a list of dictionaries obtained from parsing a column with text in json format. Below is the brief snapshot of data:

```
[{u'PAGE TYPE': u'used-serp.model.brand.city'},
 {u'BODY TYPE': u'MPV Cars',
  u'ENGINE CAPACITY': u'1461',
  u'FUEL TYPE': u' Diesel',
  u'MODEL NAME': u'Renault Lodgy',
  u'OEM NAME': u'Renault',
  u'PAGE TYPE': u'New-ModelPage.OverviewTab'},
 {u'PAGE TYPE': u'used-serp.brand.city'},
 {u'BODY TYPE': u'SUV Cars',
  u'ENGINE CAPACITY': u'2477',
  u'FUEL TYPE': u' Diesel',
  u'MODEL NAME': u'Mitsubishi Pajero',
  u'OEM NAME': u'Mitsubishi',
  u'PAGE TYPE': u'New-ModelPage.OverviewTab'},
 {u'BODY TYPE': u'Hatchback Cars',
  u'ENGINE CAPACITY': u'1198',
  u'FUEL TYPE': u' Petrol , Diesel',
  u'MODEL NAME': u'Volkswagen Polo',
  u'OEM NAME': u'Volkswagen',
  u'PAGE TYPE': u'New-ModelPage.GalleryTab'},
```

Furthermore, the code i am using to parse is detailed below:

```
stdf_noncookie = []
stdf_noncookiejson = []

for index, row in df_noncookie.iterrows():
    try:
        loop_data = json.loads(row['attributes'])
        stdf_noncookie.append(loop_data)
    except ValueError:
        loop_nondata = row['attributes']
        stdf_noncookiejson.append(loop_nondata)
```

stdf_noncookie is the list of dictionaries i am trying to convert into a pandas dataframe. 'attributes' is the column with text in json format. I have tried to get some learning from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-dataframe), however this was not able to solve my problem. Any suggestion/tips for converting a list of dictionaries to panda dataframe will be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

To convert your list of dicts to a pandas dataframe use the following:

```
stdf_noncookiejson = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

[pandas.DataFrame.from_records](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_records)

> **DataFrame.from_records** *(data, index=None, exclude=None, columns=None, coerce_float=False, nrows=None)*

You can set the index, name the columns etc as you read it in

If youre working with json you can also use the `read_json` method

```
stdf_noncookiejson = pd.read_json(data)
```

[pandas.read_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html#pandas.read_json)

> **pandas.read_json** *(path_or_buf=None, orient=None, typ='frame', dtype=True, convert_axes=True, convert_dates=True,
>   keep_default_dates=True, numpy=False, precise_float=False,
>   date_unit=None, encoding=None, lines=False)*

Answer (score 2):

Reference this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-dataframe).

Assuming d is your List of Dictionaries, simply use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you can use the pandas `DataFrame` constructor.

```
import pandas as pd

print (pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way to convert a list of dict to panda dataframe. Below is the code:

```
Method A
stdf_noncookie = df_noncookie['attributes'].apply(json.loads)
stdf_noncookie = stdf_noncookie.apply(pd.Series)

Method B
stdf_noncookie = df_noncookie['attributes'].apply(json.loads)
stdf_noncookie = pd.DataFrame(stdf_noncookie.tolist())
```

Method A is much quicker than Method B. I will create another post asking for help on the difference between the two methods. Also, on some datasets Method B is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with a list comprehension. But my problem was that I left my dict's json encoded so they looked like strings.

```
d = r.zrangebyscore('live-ticks', '-inf', time.time())
dform = [json.loads(i) for i in d]
df = pd.DataFram(dfrom)
```

Comment: there is a read json method - `pd.read_json(data)`