# Segregating odd and even numbers into separate lists - a more concise approach?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to optimize the below code. Can anyone help me::

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[]
c=[]
for i in a:
    if i%2==0:
        b.append(i)
    else:
        c.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating two lists, so instead, why not delete from one of them?

```
even = [1, 2, 3, 4]
odd = []
for i in reversed(range(len(even))):
    if even[i] % 2 != 0:
        odd.insert(0, even.pop(i))
```

`pop` removes from the first, and `insert(0, ...)` will add it to the start (in its right position). Additionally, you iterate over `b` in reverse as is common with the [reverse-delete idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49666614/4909087).

You will end up with `b` and `c` as before. Complexity wise, however, it's still the same.

---

If order isn't important, change `odd.insert(0, even.pop(i))` to `odd.append(even.pop(i))` which is slightly easier to read.