# I am trying to web scrape a website and when I am trying to turn this into a csv file, data isn't going to the correct column

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and for practice I am trying to web scrape a website and turn the results into a csv file. When I come to the part to turn the results into a csv file, it doesn't put the address in the address column. I want the data to go into the address column. The code is as follows.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.allagents.co.uk/find-agent/london/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'itemlabel3'})

filename = "webscrape.csv" 

f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Company Name, Address, Telephone Number\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    comp_name   = container.find('div', {'class':'labelleft2 col-md- 
10'}).div.h4.a.text

    address     = container.find('div', {'class':'labelleft2 col-md- 
   10'}).div.p.text

    tel         = container.find('div', {'class':'labelleft2 col-md- 
   10'}).div.find('p', {'style':'clear: both; margin-bottom: 
15px;'}).strong.text

    print("Company Name:", comp_name)
    print("Address:", address)
    print("Telephone", tel)

    f.write(comp_name.replace(",", ("|")) + "," + address.replace(",", ("|")) + 
"," + tel + "\n")

f.close()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: I'd try to avoid creating the CSV manually.  Dump your data into a pandas dataframe (that can export to csv) or use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or something.

Comment: O.K. but if I want to create a csv manually just for practice, I want to know where I have gone wrong. Also what's wrong with creating the csv manually?

Comment: re: what's wrong with creating it manually?  Nothing is *wrong* about it.  More of a no-need-to-reinvent-the-wheel type deal.  Practice is a great reason to try it manually.

Comment: Cool. Can you link any articles about making it into a pandas dataframe? Or just write an answer and show me how to do it. It seems interesting. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, if you do see where I have gone wrong originally please let me know. You can always run this code yourself if you want to try.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could attach a screenshot of the csv where you're seeing the address show up in multiple columns.  Here's what I'd do: `records = []` then in your for loop `records.append({'company': comp_name, 'address': address, 'telephone': tel})` then once you've read all the records, you can do `writer = csv.DictWriter(filename, fieldnames=['company', 'address', 'telephone'])`, `writer.writeheader()`, `for r in records: writer.writerow(r)`.  My computer can't connect to the website you linked right now so I'm having trouble running your code. I'll see if I spot the issue, tho.

Comment: In your print statements, I'd do something like `print("Address: '{}'".format(address))` in order to better see what you're reading in for those values.

Comment: I can't actually put a screenshot for some reason but there are three columns: Comany Name, Address and telephone number. In the company name column the company name goes there, but rather than the address shifting column it makes a new row and the telephone goes into the address.

Comment: Also what is the records meant to mean?

Comment: `records` is just a list of what will become each row.  The csv writer wants a dictionary to be passed when you write the row to the file so `records` stores each row's dictionary as you encounter the data.  This approach also sets you up in case you wanted to use dataframes at some point since you could [build a dataframe from that list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-dataframe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like in your address data new line character is present

try to replace below line for address in your code and try running again

```
address=(container.find('div', {'class':'labelleft2 col-md-10'}).div.p.text).replace('\n','')
```

Comment: Thanks your solution works but it kind of distorts the csv file.

Comment: This is because in address fields there are multiple spaces are there ...if you trim the spaces ....your csv will get correctly generated :)