# JSON to DataFrame for list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have two  dictionary `dict1` and `dict2`

I am trying to load them using JSON

```
import json

y = json.loads(json.dumps([dict1, dict2]))
```

then trying to convert that to pdf

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(y, orient='index')
```

I am getting below error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

when I do it for one dictionary dict1

```
x = json.loads(dict1)
df_x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient = 'index')
```

It is working. I understand that in second case as `x` is loading as dictionary it is able to convert to dataframe. But, first case, as it is a list it is not working.

So, how can I convert list of dictionaries to dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert list of dictionaries to Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-dataframe).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert list of dictionaries to Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-dataframe)