# Convert nested list of dictionaries to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

Can anyone suggest me an efficient way to convert list of list of dictionaries as pandas dataframe?

```
Input = [[{'name':'tom','roll_no':1234,'gender':'male'},
          {'name':'sam','roll_no':1212,'gender':'male'}],
          [{'name':'kavi','roll_no':1235,'gender':'female'},
          {'name':'maha','roll_no':1211,'gender':'female'}]]
```

The dictionary keys are same in the sample input provided and an expected output is,

```
Output =      name       roll_no       gender
          0   tom        1234          male
          1   sam        1212          male
          2   kavi       1235          female
          3   maha       1211          female
```

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate, especially [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831756/4909087) to that question.

Comment: The section "Summarising"  in your answer has covered the nested dictionaries in a list, but not what I have asked i.e., nested list inside list with dictionaries.

Comment: Oh, ummmm, just flatten the lists; `from itertools import chain; pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(Input)))` it is quite simple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is that mention in your answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe/53831756#53831756] ?

Comment: You are right, it is not. Will reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to flatten your input using `itertools.chain`, and you can then call the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

```
from itertools import chain
pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(data)))

   gender  name  roll_no
0    male   tom     1234
1    male   sam     1212
2  female  kavi     1235
3  female  maha     1211
```