# "None of [Index(['', ''], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm  panda library  in python  getting error

"None of [Index(['Dokuman', 'Sinif'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

```
classes = ['ekonomi', 'spor', 'teknoloji', 'teknoloji', 'saglik', 'saglik', 'spor', 'ekonomi']

df_docs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Dokuman': docs, 'Sinif': classes}, orient='index')


df_docs = df_docs[['Dokuman', 'Sinif']] #throws the error here
```

Comment: Don't use `orient='index'` if you don't want your data oriented along the index (use `'columns'`)

Comment: Or better still, just `df_docs = pd.DataFrame({...})` is enough

Comment: i changed the code
df_docs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Dokuman': docs, 'Sinif': classes})
"arrays must all be same length"  I got the error

Comment: i changed the code

df_docs = pd.DataFrame({'Dokuman': docs, 'Sinif': classes})

ı got the error "arrays must all be same length"

Comment: How there is no other method ?

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe/53831756#53831756 there's information on loading a DataFrame if the length of the lists are not equal.

Comment: thanks @coldspeed just like you said. the number of records in the docs is not equal to the number of records in the classes, so I am getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the number of records in the docs is not equal to the number of records in the classes, so I am getting the error