# How to make a list of dictionaries from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to try to set up a list with specific dictionaries. I would like the structure to be something similar to the following:

```
[{'label': 'Abdelnaby, Alaa', 'value': '76001'},
{'label': 'Abdul-Aziz, Zaid', 'value': '76002'},
{'label': 'Abdul-Jabbar, Kareem', 'value': '76003'}]
```

Currently, the data that I am pulling from is in a pandas dataframe. Example below...

```
PlayerID    Name     Current Player First Season    Last Season
76001   Abdelnaby, Alaa       0     1990            1994
76002   Abdul-Aziz, Zaid      0     1968            1977
76003   Abdul-Jabbar, Kareem  0     1969            1988
51      Abdul-Rauf, Mahmoud   0     1990            2000
1505    Abdul-Wahad, Tariq    0     1997            2003
```

Please let me know​ if this is sufficient. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select your columns, rename them and call `to_dict` with `orient='records'` to get a list of dicts,

```
(df.reindex(['Name', 'PlayerID'], axis=1)
   .set_axis(['label', 'value'], axis=1, inplace=False)
   .to_dict('r'))    

# [{'label': 'Abdelnaby, Alaa', 'value': 76001},
#  {'label': 'Abdul-Aziz, Zaid', 'value': 76002},
#  {'label': 'Abdul-Jabbar, Kareem', 'value': 76003},
#  {'label': 'Abdul-Rauf, Mahmoud', 'value': 51},
#  {'label': 'Abdul-Wahad, Tariq', 'value': 1505}]
```

You can output JSON by changing `.to_dict('r')` to `.to_json(orient='records')`.

---

If performance matters, here is an optimised solution with list comprehension construction.

```
[dict(zip(('label', 'value'), r)) for r in df[['Name', 'PlayerID']].values]

# [{'label': 'Abdelnaby, Alaa', 'value': 76001},
#  {'label': 'Abdul-Aziz, Zaid', 'value': 76002},
#  {'label': 'Abdul-Jabbar, Kareem', 'value': 76003},
#  {'label': 'Abdul-Rauf, Mahmoud', 'value': 51},
#  {'label': 'Abdul-Wahad, Tariq', 'value': 1505}]
```

Comment: Conversely, if you want to convert these list of dicts back into a DataFrame, you can see how to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831756/4909087).

Comment: just curious, why use .reindex(axis =1), over just using [[ ]] and selecting the columns?

Comment: @BenPap method chaining all the way!

Comment: @coldspeed I guess dictionary comprehension might be little bit faster in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If speed is the issue we can use dict comp:

```
myjson = [{'label': name, 'value': pid} for pid,name in zip(df['PlayerID'], df['Name'])]
```

Gives:

```
[{'label': 'Abdelnaby, Alaa', 'value': 76001},
 {'label': 'Abdul-Aziz, Zaid', 'value': 76002},
 {'label': 'Abdul-Jabbar, Kareem', 'value': 76003},
 {'label': 'Abdul-Rauf, Mahmoud', 'value': 51},
 {'label': 'Abdul-Wahad, Tariq', 'value': 1505}]
```

Further, If you want to write the data as **json**:

```
import json
with open('myjson.json','w') as fo:
    json.dump(myjson,fo,indent=4)
```

## Speed comparison

```
%%timeit
myjson = [{'label': name, 'value': pid} for pid,name in zip(df['PlayerID'].values, df['Name'].values)]

5.9 µs ± 125 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)



%%timeit
myjson = (df.reindex(['Name', 'PlayerID'], axis=1)
   .set_axis(['label', 'value'], axis=1, inplace=False)
   .to_dict('record')
)
756 µs ± 24.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

PlayerID    Name     Current Player First Season    Last Season
76001   Abdelnaby, Alaa       0     1990            1994
76002   Abdul-Aziz, Zaid      0     1968            1977
76003   Abdul-Jabbar, Kareem  0     1969            1988
51      Abdul-Rauf, Mahmoud   0     1990            2000
1505    Abdul-Wahad, Tariq    0     1997            2003

```
#You already have a data frame 
dataframe="your data frame"
#us iloc 
values=dataframe.iloc[:,0]# u have all rows n 0th col
label=dataframe.iloc[:,1] #u have all rows n 1st col
dic={}

    for i,val in values:
         dic[val]=lable[i]

#hope the logic is clear.
```