# Pandas create a DataFrame from a list of dictionaries with an index column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries that look like this.

```
d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}....]
```

I am trying to construct a DataFrame from this as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=['a'])
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (X, 2), indices imply (1, 2)
```

(X is a number of items I have in d)

Answer (score 2):

I will using [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_records)

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(d,index='a')
Out[26]: 
   b
a   
1  2
2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('a')
```

Comment: What does the index argument in the constructor do? Why can't I create a DataFrame directly with the index column!

Comment: The index argument in the constructer expects a list or series. In other words it expects all index values to be provided as a list.

You could use the index argument but you would need to traverse your list of dictionaries to gather the index values in the form of a list to do so.

i.e.
pd.DataFrame.from_records(d,index=[record['a'] for record in d])

May as well just let pandas ingest the list of dictionaries as records then assign one of the columns as the index.

Answer (score 1):

Because I cannot comment. See here [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

And Quang Hoang is correct. This is analogous to timeseries data. You want to set the index after the dataframe has been built.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('a')
```

The index argument in the constructor expects a list or a series so setting it as 'a' will mean there is only 1 row. However setting the index to the column 'a' after the dataframe has been built, sets the index to the series represented by the column 'a'. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html