# Specify ordering for columns when creating a DataFrame from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a method that creates a list, results, and then appends to it a dict row which has keys (column names in my eventual dataframe) and values (row values in my eventual dataframe). Then I append the row and convert the results collection to a df at the end. For example:

```
results = []
row = {}
row['Name']="alice"
row['Age']=3
results.append(row)
..reset row, fill in values like above, and append more rows..

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

The issue I have is that the column names are alphbetized so the df looks like this:

```
df.head()
|Age |  Name  |
|3   | alice  |
```

Is there a way to specify the column names to be in the order I want ("Name", "Col")? In reality I have many more columns so I'd prefer not to have to do:

```
cols = df.columns
cols = cols[:1] + cols[0:1]
```

and manually rearrange it. However, if I do so, does that just move around the column row or also the rows below? So, will "alice" and 3 in the row below also get moved around while moving the column as one would expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a list of your desired ordering to the `columns` attribute, and `DataFrame` will reorder the columns when creating the DataFrame.

```
pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Name', 'Age'])

    Name  Age
0  alice    3
```

Or, `DataFrame.from_records` does this as well.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(results, columns=['Name', 'Age'])

    Name  Age
0  alice    3
```

If you're working with multiple columns, you could always choose to do `columns=['Name', 'Age', *(row.keys() - {'Name', 'Age'})]` assuming you don't care about the ordering of the remaining columns.

I've written about constructing DataFrames from records in this post: [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe/53831756#53831756)

---

Another idea, fix the columns if the ordering is incorrect.

```
if df.columns.get_loc('Age') < df.columns.get_loc('Name'):
    df.insert(df.columns.get_loc('Age'), 'Name', df.pop('Name'))
```

This will insert Name before Age if it is originally inserted after.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results,columns=list(row.keys()))
#from collections import OrderedDict :alternative
#columns=[i for i in OrderedDict.fromkeys(row.keys())]
print(df)
```

---

```
    Name  Age
0  alice    3
```

Comment: Will the guarantee the desired ordering on python versions <3.6?

Comment: @cs95 good point, not tested for `<3.6` , works for my version. :) how about `[i for i in OrderedDict.fromkeys(row.keys())]` ??

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), as of pandas 0.23 and python 3.6, when constructing from dicts, the order will be maintained. You could simply use an `OrderedDict`.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict


results = []
row = OrderedDict()

row['Name']="alice"
row['Age']=3
results.append(row)
#..reset row, fill in values like above, and append more rows..

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df.head())
```

```
    Name  Age
0  alice    3
```

Comment: This is only under the assumption that they are creating the records from scratch (this usually isn't the case, but still a valid suggestion).