# Save DataFrame to next row in existing excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Ideally I'm building a self-updating mechanism. The last thing I need to do is save content from "dff" to the next empty row in an existing excel sheet "test.xlsx".

[image: Existing excel sheet "test.xlsx"]

```
book = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
dff.to_excel(writer, startrow=len(dff), header=None)
writer.save()
```

The issue is around the 2nd last row, the "startrow=" part.
So far I can make it enter the dataframe content to row 3, but it overwrites the contents.

Say I have content
08/09-2019 00, 00, 00, 00
How would I add it to the next empty row of my excel sheet?

Comment: does it overwrite whole data or just one row?

Comment: it overwrites just one row - row 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
dff.to_excel(writer, startrow=len(dff)+1, header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: This writes to the row 4, but overwrites it. I would need it to write to row 5, 6, 7 etc. eventually.

Comment: but if I say startrow=len(dff)+2 it writes to row 5. How can I make startrow +1 automatically?

Comment: you can try to get len of actual book and then try to add the new df

Comment: Could you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: i mean startrow= len(writer.book)+1