# pandas group by day or week or month for timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a pandas beginner.

I have the following data:

```
a = [{"content": '1', "time": 1577870427}, 
     {"content": '4', "time": 1577870427},
     {"content": '2', "time": 1577956827},
     {"content": '3', "time": 1580548827}, 
     {"content": '4', "time": 1580635227},
     {"content": '5', "time": 1583054427}, 
     {"content": '6', "time": 1583140827}]
```

And I want:

```
2020-01: [
     {"content": '1', "time": '2020-01-01'},
     {"content": '4', "time": '2020-01-01'},
     {"content": '2', "time": '2020-01-02'},
    ]

    2020-02: [
     {"content": '3', "time": '2020-02-01'}, 
     {"content": '4', "time": '2020-02-02'},
    ]

    2020-03: [
     {"content": '5', "time": '2020-03-01'}, 
     {"content": '6', "time": '2020-03-02'}
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert column `time` to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `unit` parameter and for custom format use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
d = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
df['time'] = d.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
g = d.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

d1 = {k: v.to_dict('r') for k, v in df.groupby(g)}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should convert your list of dictionaries into a pandas `DataFrame`. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe), this is rather easy:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

next you want to convert your `time` column into date-time objects rather than integers. The best way I know to do this is the [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function in pandas. Please see the documentation for further Details.

```
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], unit = 's') #should do the trick, but could not test yet...
```

For the actual grouping, pandas provides the very powerful [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function, which is implemented for all `DataFrame` objects. Again, the docs will provide detailed information.

```
data.groupby(['time'])
```

please note that if the output is not exactly what you want, you can easily modify it using `groupby` because it accepts mappings, functions, labels or lists of labels as an argument. This should allow you to get exactly what you want, if you play with it a little.

Comment: Data conversion not worked in this case, I used `data.time = data.time.apply(lambda d: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` instead.

Comment: glad you found a way, I don't deal with timestamps that often. I am sure there is a way to use `to_datetime`... but I am not the expert here.

Comment: I've checked once again and `pd.to_datetime` is ok, but there is typo: should be `unit = 's'` not `units = 's'`. So usage of lambda function  is not needed.