# Python Methods Refactoring for Filtering Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of Dictionaries where the Dictionaries have the following structure:

```py
{
    "subject" : "subjectValue",
    "object" : "objectValue",
    "prediction" : "predictionValue"
}
```

Currently i have three Methods to filter all Dictionaries from the list for each of the fields like this:

```py
def getSubjects(value, objectValue, predictionValue):
    return [stmt["subject"] for stmt in value if stmt["object"] == objectValue and stmt["prediction"] == predicitonValue]

def getObjects(value, subjectValue, predictionValue):
    return [stmt["object"] for stmt in value if stmt["subject"] == subjectValue and stmt["prediction"] == predicitonValue]

def getPredictions(value, objectValue, subjectValue):
    return [stmt["prediction"] for stmt in value if stmt["object"] == objectValue and stmt["subject"] == subjectValue]
```

I also have the following three methods to just get one of the Dictionaries out of the list:

```py
def getSubject(value, objectValue, predictionValue):
    return next(stmt["subject"] for stmt in value if if stmt["object"] == objectValue and stmt["prediction"] == predicitonValue)

def getObject(value, subjectValue, predictionValue):
    return next(stmt["object"] for stmt in value if stmt["subject"] == subjectValue and stmt["prediction"] == predicitonValue)

def getPrediction(value, objectValue, subjectValue):
    return next(stmt["prediction"] for stmt in value if stmt["object"] == objectValue and stmt["subject"] == subjectValue)
```

Is there a better way to achive this? Maybe in one single Method or in a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the `next()` functions by always returning an iterator instead of a list. Then you can either call `next()` or `list()` on the returned value. To generalize, you could require that the function is called with keyword arguments representing the keys you want to match along with the key you want to return. The signature would look like:

```
def pluckFilter(ds, key, **filters):
```

And you could call it like:

```
pluckFilter(listOfDicts, 'object', subject = 'subjectValue2', prediction = 'predictionValue' )
```

This would allow a pretty simple implementation (although you might want to validate the input):

```
listOfDicts = [{
    "subject" : "subjectValue",
    "object" : "objectValue",
    "prediction" : "predictionValue"
    },
    {
    "subject" : "subjectValue2",
    "object" : "objectValue",
    "prediction" : "predictionValue"
    }
]

def pluckFilter(ds, key, **filters):
    filtered = filter(lambda d: all(d[filt] == filters[filt] for filt in filters), ds)
    return map(lambda d: d[key], filtered)

list(pluckFilter(listOfDicts, 'subject', object = 'objectValue', prediction = 'predictionValue' ))
# ['subjectValue', 'subjectValue2']

next(pluckFilter(listOfDicts, 'subject', object = 'objectValue', prediction = 'predictionValue' ))
# 'subjectValue'

list(pluckFilter(listOfDicts, 'object', subject = 'subjectValue2', prediction = 'predictionValue' ))
# ['objectValue']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)?

You can [convert the list of dictionaries into pandas `DataFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe). And then use convenient filtering to get the same values as the functions you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict, index=range(len(list_of_dict)))
```

e.g. analogon of `getSubject`:

```
subjects = subjects = df.loc[(df["object"] == 'objectValue')  & (df["prediction"] == 'predictionValue'), 'subject']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a SQLite3 database or a Pandas Data Frame. [SQLite3 tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/sql-database-python-part-1-inserting-database/)

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(subject REAL, object REAL, prediction REAL)")

c.execute("INSERT INTO my_table(subject, object, prediction) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
          (10, 20, 30))

c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")

data = c.fetchall()

for row in data:
    print(row)

c.close()
conn.close()
```