# Python: Response object to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to turn a request response into a pandas dataframe.

So far I have turned it into a string and just browsed Google for a bit. My first language was technically python but when I was learning python anything 3.X was experimental so it's been a while, plus pandas is a whole other beast.

ANYWAYS, trying to turn this into a dataframe, any ideas or links I should check out?:

THE BELOW IS A STRING, NOT A DICTIONARY. I even try

```
from ast import literal_eval
...
ast.literal_eval(data)
```

and this also does not work .. hmmm

```
{
  "instrument": "EUR_USD",
  "granularity": "S5",
  "candles": [
    {
      "complete": true,
      "volume": 7,
      "time": "2020-07-14T19:33:50.000000000Z",
      "mid": {
        "o": "1.13925",
        "h": "1.13926",
        "l": "1.13922",
        "c": "1.13922"
      }
    },
    {
      "complete": true,
      "volume": 1,
      "time": "2020-07-14T19:33:55.000000000Z",
      "mid": {
        "o": "1.13921",
        "h": "1.13921",
        "l": "1.13921",
        "c": "1.13921"
      }
    },
    {
      "complete": true,
      "volume": 1,
      "time": "2020-07-14T19:34:00.000000000Z",
      "mid": {
        "o": "1.13920",
        "h": "1.13920",
        "l": "1.13920",
        "c": "1.13920"
      }
    },
    {
      "complete": false,
      "volume": 10,
      "time": "2020-07-14T19:34:10.000000000Z",
      "mid": {
        "o": "1.13921",
        "h": "1.13921",
        "l": "1.13916",
        "c": "1.13920"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(data['candles'])` reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831756/4909087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `pandas` module and the `DataFrame()` function from it.

```
a = {
  "instrument": "EUR_USD",
  "granularity": "S5",
  "candles": [
    {
      "complete": True,
      "volume": 7,
      "time": "2020-07-14T19:33:50.000000000Z",
      "mid": {
        "o": "1.13925",
        "h": "1.13926",
        "l": "1.13922",
        "c": "1.13922"
      }
    },
    {
      "complete": True,
      "volume": 1,
      "time": "2020-07-14T19:33:55.000000000Z",
      "mid": {
        "o": "1.13921",
        "h": "1.13921",
        "l": "1.13921",
        "c": "1.13921"
      }
    },
    {
      "complete": True,
      "volume": 1,
      "time": "2020-07-14T19:34:00.000000000Z",
      "mid": {
        "o": "1.13920",
        "h": "1.13920",
        "l": "1.13920",
        "c": "1.13920"
      }
    },
    {
      "complete": False,
      "volume": 10,
      "time": "2020-07-14T19:34:10.000000000Z",
      "mid": {
        "o": "1.13921",
        "h": "1.13921",
        "l": "1.13916",
        "c": "1.13920"
      }
    }
  ]
}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```