# How to convert key value list into array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of key value pairs like this

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020/9/15",
        "amount": "10",
        "desc": "test 1"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/9/16",
        "amount": "25",
        "desc": "test 2"
    }
]
```

And I would like to convert this into like this by Python

```
[
    ["date", "amount", "desc"],
    ["2020/9/15", "10", "test 1"],
    ["2020/9/16", "25", "test 2"]
]
```

Do I just have to make a loop to do this?
Would anyone guide me a better way to do?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `list(dicts[0]) + [list(d.values()) for d in dicts]` works nicely (though in earlier versions of python-3, before dictionary order was stipulated, it might not work as intended).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go for something like this:

```
lis = [
    {
        "date": "2020/9/15",
        "amount": "10",
        "desc": "test 1"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/9/16",
        "amount": "25",
        "desc": "test 2"
    }
]

out = [list(lis[0])] + [list(dic.values()) for dic in lis]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[['date', 'amount', 'desc'], 
['2020/9/15', '10', 'test 1'], 
['2020/9/16', '25', 'test 2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        "date": "2020/9/15",
        "amount": "10",
        "desc": "test 1"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/9/16",
        "amount": "25",
        "desc": "test 2"
    }
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
output =  [df.columns.to_list()] + df.values.tolist()
```

Output

```
[['date', 'amount', 'desc'],
['2020/9/15', '10', 'test 1'],
['2020/9/16', '25', 'test 2']]
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a problem that could elegantly be handled by the dataframe handling provided by the Pandas library.

See: [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You can add that as a comment too

Comment: @Karthik Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately the `New contributor' tag does not allow me to comment anyone else's posts, as 50 reputation is the minimum required for that action. I will keep it in mind for the future.